# Tips for golfing in MATLAB

Tags: code-golf, tips, matlab

What general tips do you have for golfing in MATLAB? I'm looking for ideas that can be applied to code golf problems in general that are at least somewhat specific to MATLAB (e.g. "remove comments" is not an answer). Please post one tip per answer.

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate: [Tips for golfing in Octave](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12975/tips-for-golfing-in-octave)

Answer (score 10):

Something that one must know before starting to golf:

In MATLAB calculations a character behaves the same as its ascii code.

```
'abc' - 'a'  % Returns: [0 1 2]
'123' - '0'  % Returns: [1 2 3]
'“' == 8220  % Returns: 1 (logical)
'a':'e'==100 % Returns: [0 0 0 1 0] (logical)
```

Answer (score 10):

Shortening property names

In MATLAB, strings identifying properties can be shortened as long as it does not result in ambiguity.

```
plot(X,'C','k') % Ambiguous property found.
plot(X,'Co','k') % Expands to Color  (black)
```

This actually [won](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/45736/fifty-shades-of-grey/46871#46871) me a challenge :)

Comment: Very nice, though the answer is correct I want to emphasize that this applies to the name of `name, value` pairs as shown above. (So not to things like `sort(rand(4,1),'descend')`)

Comment: It does apply to some of those things too, like `conv(1:5,[1 1],'s')` instead of `conv(1:5,[1 1],'same')`

Answer (score 6):

Casting as char can be done by concatenation with a char:

```
x='a'+magic(5) % Array with character codes of several letters

char(x) % The standard way
['' x] % The compact way
```

Though it only saves one char, this can be used quite frequently.

Answer (score 5):

Strings are just character row vectors. This means that instead of

```matlab
for i=numel(str)
    a=str(i)
    ...
end
```

you can simply write

```matlab
for(a=str)
    ...
end
```

First time I used this: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58387/32352

Answer (score 4):

<sub>Related, but not identical [tips for Octave](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111980/31516).</sub>

A little known and little used feature of both MATLAB and Octave is that most builtin functions can be called without parentheses, in which case they will treat whatever follows it as a string (as long as it doesn't contain spaces). If it contains spaces you need quotation marks. This can frequently be used to save a byte when using `disp`:

```
disp('Hello, World!')
disp 'Hello, World!'
```

Other, less useful examples include:

```
nnz PPCG
ans = 4

size PPCG
ans = 1  4

str2num 12
ans = 12
```

I've actually used this twice in the *["How high can you count?"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/124362/31516)*-challenge:

```
strchr sssssssssssssst t
```

is equivalent to `strchr('sssssssssssssst','t')` and returns `15`.

```
nnz nnnnnnnnnnnnnn
```

is equivalent to `nnz('nnnnnnnnnnnnnn')` and returns `14`.

Stuff like `gt r s` works too (equivalent to `'r'>'s'` or `gt('r','s')`.

Answer (score 4):

## Roots of unity via discrete Fourier transform

Given a positive integer `n`, the standard way to generate the `n`-th [roots of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity) is

```
exp(2j*pi*(0:n-1)/n)
```

This gives the roots starting at `1` and moving in the positive angular direction. If order doesn't matter, this can be shortened to

```
exp(2j*pi*(1:n)/n)
```

---

Since `exp(2j*pi/4)` equals the imaginary unit (`j`), this can be written more compactly as follows (trick [due to @flawr](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/101855/36398)):

```
j.^(4*(0:n-1)/n)
```

or

```
j.^(4*(1:n)/n)
```

---

But the [discrete Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) provides an even shorter way (thanks to @flawr for removing two unnecessary parentheses):

```
fft(1:n==n)
```

which gives the roots starting at `1` and moving in the positive angular direction; or

```
fft(1:n==2)
```

which starts at `1` and moves in the negative angular direction.

---

Try all of the above [here](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/T8FWwdiaK7WiQMMoS6sgU0vDwCpP11BTP08TWdDQKg8slKUXp2GCrAYqAJNPSysBsW1tkdlGmv//AwA).

Comment: Great trick! You can even golf it down to `fft(1:n==2)`

Comment: @flawr I never know the precedence rules... Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`nnz` can sometimes save you a few bytes:

- Imagine you want the sum of a logical matrix `A`. Instead of `sum(sum(A))` or `sum(A(:))`, you can use `nnz(a)` (`nnz` implitictly applies `(:)`).
- If you want to know the number of elements of an array, and you can be sure there are no zeros, instead of `numel(x)` you can use `nnz(x)`. This is applicable for instance if `x` is a string.

Answer (score 3):

Iteration over vectors in matrices.

Given a set of vector as matrix, you can actually iterate over them via a single for loop like

```
for v=M
    disp(v);
end
```

while "traditionally" you probably would have done it like

```
for k=1:n
    disp(M(:,k));
end
```

I've only learned about this trick just now from @Suever in [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/82410/24877).

Answer (score 3):

#### 2D Convolution Kernels

This is maybe a niche topic, but apparently some people like to use convolution for various things here. <sup>[citation needed]</sup>

In 2D following kernels are often needed:

```
0 1 0
1 1 1
0 1 0
```

This can be achieved using

```
v=[1,2,1];v'*v>1 %logical
v=[1,0,1];1-v'*v  %as numbers
```

which is shorter than

```
[0,1,0;1,1,1;0,1,0]
```

Another kernel often used is

```
0 1 0
1 0 1
0 1 0
```

which can be shortened using

```
v=[1,-1,1];v'*v<0   % logical
[0,1,0;1,0,1;0,1,0] % naive verison
```

Comment: Second kernel as numbers, same byte count: `toeplitz([0 1 0])`

Answer (score 2):

I quite often find myself using `meshgrid` or `ndgrid`, let's say we want to compute a mandelbrot image, then we initialize e.g.

```
[x,y]=meshgrid(-2:1e-2:1,-1:1e-2,1)
```

Now for the mandelbrot set we need another matrix `c` of the size of `x` and `y` but initialized with zeros. This can easily be done by writing:

```
c=x*0;
```

You can also initialize it to another value:

```
c=x*0+3;
```

But you can actually save some bytes by just adding another dimension in `meshgrid/ndgrid`:

```
[x,y,c]=meshgrid(-2:1e-2:1,-1:1e_2,1, 0); %or for the value 3
[x,y,c]=meshgrid(-2:1e-2:1,-1:1e_2,1, 3);
```

And you can do this as often as you want:

```
[x,y,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5]=meshgrid(-2:1e-2:1,-1:1e_2,1, 1,pi,exp(3),1e5,-3i)
```

Comment: Note that in the meantime there is automatic broadcasting: In many cases the first example could be replaced by `x=-2:1d-2:1;y=x'`.

Answer (score 2):

The built-in `ones` and `zeros` are a typically a waste of space. You can achieve the same result by simply multiplying an array/matrix (of the desired size) by 0 (to get the output of `zeros`) and add 1 if you want the output of `ones`.

```
d = rand(5,2);

%// Using zeros
z = zeros(size(d));

%// Not using zeros
z = d*0;

%// Using ones
o = ones(size(d));

%// Not using ones
o = 1+d*0
```

This also works if you want to create a column or row vector of zeros or ones the size of one dimension of a matrix.

```
p = rand(5,2);

z = zeros(size(p,1), 1);
z = 0*p(:,1);

o = ones(size(p, 1), 1);
o = 1+0*p(:,1);
```

If you want to create a matrix of a specific size you could use `zeros` but you could also just assign the last element to 0 and have MATLAB fill in the rest.

```
%// This
z = zeros(2,3);

%// vs. This
z(2,3) = 0;
```

Comment: I like to use `~(1:n)` for 1-d zero vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Counting the number of non zero elements in a matrix

```matlab
zeronum(i)=nnz C;
zeronum(i)=nnz(C);
zeronum(i)=sum(C~=0);
zeronum(i)=sum(abs(C)>=eps);
zeronum(i)=numel(find(C~=0));
zeronum(i)=prod(size(find(C~=0)));
```

Horizontal replication is 3 copies, vertical replication is 2 copies

```matlab
repmat([1,2;3,4],2,3)
kron(ones(2,3),[1,2;3,4])
```

Multiple variables, all initialized with the same data

```matlab
[A,B,C,D]=deal([1 4;2 5;3 6]);

%%%%
A = [1 4; 2 5; 3 6];
B=A;
C=A;
D=A;
```

Declare a zero matrix of the same size as matrix A

```matlab
X=0*A(:,1);
X=zeros(size(A));
X=zeros(size(A),'like',A);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Summation of a sequence of functions

- For summing up functions f(x_n) where n is a vector of consecutive integers, feval is adviced rather than symsum.

  ```
  Syms x;symsum(f(x),x,1,n);
  Sum(feval(@(x)f(x),1:n));
  ```

  Notice that an elementary operation `.*` and `./` is necessary instead of pairwise binary operations `*` and `/`
- If the function can be naively written no one from either last ways is suitable.

  for example if the function is `log` you can simply do: `sum(log(1:n))` , which represents:

  ```
  Sum(f(1:n));
  ```

  for relatively sophisticated functions as `log(n)/x^n` you can do:

  ```
  Sum(log(1:n)./5.^(1:n))
  ```

  and even shorter in some cases when a function is longer as `f(x)=e^x+sin(x)*log(x)/x`....

  ```
  Sum(feval(@(y)e.^(y)+sin(y).*log(y)./y,1:n))
  ```

  that is remarkably shorter than `sum(feval(@(y)e.^(1:n)+sin(1:n).*log(1:n)./(1:n),1:n))`

---

**Note:** This trick can be applied for other inclusive operators as `prod` or `mean`

---