# Transform a matrix

Tags: code-golf, math, matrix

Write a program or function where a matrix A (maximum value of dimensions of the matrix is 100) is transformed to a new matrix B. Each element of the new matrix B is the sum of the positive neighbors of the corresponding element of the matrix A.

Only neighbors in the four orthogonal directions are considered, and the edges do not wrap around.

Example input:

```
 1  2  3
 4 -1 -2
-3 -4 10
 1  2 10
```

Output:

```
 6  4  2
 1  6 13
 5 12 10
 2 11 12
```

Rules:

- As input use integers.
- This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! All challenges here require an objective winning criterion, in order to indisputably determine which solution should win. Typically, this is [tag:code-golf], which means that the shortest code in bytes wins. Furthermore, it would be helpful to specify the valid input/output formats (2d array? single string? etc.). Finally, there are some edge cases you haven't covered; for example, will a number ever be surrounded only by negative numbers?

Comment: Thank you. I guess up to[100][100], and yes a number will be surrounded by negative numbers.

Comment: In what ways can we take input?

Comment: @Doorknob The sum of an empty set of numbers is 0.

Comment: @Maltysen STDIN, I guess.

Comment: @M.T Can we also take the input through function arguments?

Comment: @R.Kap yes, you can.

Comment: I was talking about if it could be as a string, list of strings, list of lists on ints, etc.

Comment: @Maltysen ints.

Comment: Are builtins disallowed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 9 bytes

```
t0>*1Y6Z+
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=dDA-KjFZNlor&input=WzEgMiAzOzQgLTEgLTI7LTMgLTQgMTA7MSAyIDEwXQ)

#### Explanation

The input matrix is multplied by an appropriate mask to make negative values equal to 0. Then a 2D convolution is applied to compute the sum of neighbours of each entry.

```
t     % Take input implicitly: 2D array. Duplicate
0>    % Is each entry positive? This gives a mask of positive values
*     % Multiply: set negative values of input array to zero
1Y6   % Predefined literal: [0 1 0; 1 0 1; 0 1 0]
Z+    % 2D convolution preserving size. Implicitly display
```

Comment: Are phones allowed as I/O?

Comment: Well then, I doubt it if this is beatable :p

Comment: @Adnan In Python it's not

Comment: This guy did this while on the phone, and here I am, having to *dedicate* some of my time to trying to solve some of these problems...

Comment: @R.Kap I meant "typed from the phone" (not "typed while talking on the phone"). Sorry about my English :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo Either way -- these sorts of problems require a lot of time and trial and error on my part (partially because I purposefully use unconventional, challenging languages)

Answer (score 7):

## Octave, <s>46</s> <s>44</s> 40 bytes

<s>Saved 2 bytes thanks to [@flawr](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/24877/flawr)</s>
[@LuisMendo's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo) kernel was 4 bytes shorter than @flawr's.

```
@(M)conv2(M.*(M>0),(x='aba')~=x','same')
```

Just like [@LuisMendo's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78652/42892) answer! Only less... golfy.

You can see it here on [ideone](http://ideone.com/ov2cuv).

Comment: COMON, I was just about to post this exact answer.

Comment: @flawr LOL! Golf is a game of speed! Wait, what?

Comment: PS: If you switch to matlab you can replace `'same'` with `'s'` But the convolution kernels should be more golfable...

Comment: @flawr I thought about that, but 1) I don't have MATLAB, and 2) it doesn't work on ideone. :(

Comment: `mod(spiral(3)+1,2)` would be one shorter=)

Comment: Two shoter: `[m=0:1,0;1,m;m,0]` (I feel proud=)

Comment: You can use save 6 bytes using `(x='aba')~=x'` instead of `[0 1 0;1 0 1;0 1 0]`

Comment: @LuisMendo What is this witchcraft?

Comment: My google-fu is failing me. What the Torvalds does `M.*(<boolean>)` do?

Comment: @cat `.*` is element-wise matrix multiplication. The boolean matrix is, MATLAB being largely typeless, treated as numeric. So `M>0` is just acting as a mask.

Comment: @LuisMendo Do you have to destroy every last bit of my self esteem???

Comment: @flawr :-P ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @LuisMendo =) Sadly this one does not work in Matlab, you'd need to use some bsxfun or so...

Comment: @flawr In Matlab you can't do that "intermediate" assignment to `x` either

Comment: @LuisMendo I know, I'm just looking for ways of golfing those kernels in matlab too=)

Comment: @flawr If you have the Comm Toolbox, you can use `~de2bi([5 2 5])`

Comment: `(x='aba')~=x'`. That's just awesome @Luis!

Comment: @StewieGriffin It's crazy what you can do in Octave with those intermediate assignments!

Comment: @LuisMendo Is that one in the Octave Tips thread yet?

Comment: @beaker It is more or less [covered](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12975/36398), yes

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>99</s> 94 bytes

```
a=>a.map((b,i)=>b.map((_,j)=>(g=(c=j,k=j)=>c[k]>0&&c[k])(a[i-1])+g(a[i+1])+g(b,j-1)+g(b,j+1)))
```

Accepts and returns a two-dimensional array.

Edit: Completely rewritten when I discovered that default arguments work when you pass an explicitly undefined value, such as when you index off the end of an array.

Comment: Related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78671/44704

Comment: @Socialz Neils version is older.

Comment: @flawr Some people might be looking at this message chain in vote order, not the post date order, hence I commented that related answer. This one is 4 bytes longer than user's one.

Comment: So you basically want to advertise the other post??

Comment: @Socialz Was 4 bytes longer, yes ;-)

Comment: I'm not letting you get ahead that easy. ;)

Comment: This is getting exciting! JS war!

Comment: @Socialz Sorry, I don't think I can match his latest result, although at least I'm still not 4 bytes longer.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>95</s> 93 bytes

```js
document.write("<pre>"+(

m=>m.map((a,r)=>a.map((_,c)=>(s=(x,y=0)=>(n=(m[r+y]||0)[c+x])>0&&n)(1)+s(-1)+s(0,1)+s(0,-1)))

)([[  1,  2,  3 ],
   [  4, -1, -2 ],
   [ -3, -4, 10 ],
   [  1,  2, 10 ]])

.join`\n`)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python with SciPy, 127 bytes

```py
from scipy.signal import*
lambda A,r=range(3):convolve2d([[x*(x>0)for x in y]for y in A],[[0,1,0],[1,0,1],[0,1,0]],mode='same')
```

This computes the result using [Luis Mendo's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78652/45941).

[Try it online](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwli8EKhCAURfdB__B2abwGq1kNOOB3iAunNITUsIj6-1Ha3HfO416bood9ctv92t0S9ArObzEdbV1Zvmr_mzUITDzpsBgy0s8UwxnX0wwzkfJqyfVl1MYEF7gAtyp4FxQKpWTYI8uQE_t8H1fo42x4s2tvGlpXdSW4zB0YEEaFIN8IXdZuKNKNmfKnZ8WeVmZVdlty4QBLBP0DOjs3fQ==&lang=sage)

Answer (score 0):

### Mathcad,  bytes

Uses standard 2D convolution of the filtered array with a 3x3 kernel.  Variants with negative element sums and diagonal kernel also added as part compensation for the program not being in the running for least bytes.

[image]

---

No byte count entered as Mathcad scoring has yet to be determined.  However, using keyboard equivalence, it is the region of 28 bytes assuming that matrix input doesn't count towards the total.

Note that what you see in the image above is exactly how the solutionn is entered and displayed in Mathcad.

Answer (score 0):

## Jelly, <s>23</s> <s>20</s> 18 bytes

```
0;+ḊṖ
ZÇ€Z+Ç€
+AHÇ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=MDsr4biK4bmWClrDh-KCrForw4figqwKK0FIw4c&input=&args=WzEsMiwzXSxbNCwtMSwtMl0sWy0zLC00LDEwXSxbMSwyLDEwXQ)

### Algorithm

Let's say there is only one row: [1,2,3,4].

Let's say A is the result of prepending a zero, i.e. [0,1,2,3,4].

B is the result of removing the first item, i.e. [2,3,4].

Then the final result is simply A+B vectorized, then removing the last item.

Now, the algorithm is to apply this to every row as well as every column, then find their vectorized sum.

#### To each column?! I thought Jelly does not support this...

You're right. Therefore, I transposed it, applied to each row, then transposed it again.

#### Algorithm for removing negative numbers

Here, you just add to each number their absolute. It effectively eliminates negative numbers while doubling each positive number. Then, just halve the whole matrix.

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 36 bytes

```
Lm+Vt+d0+0dbJmm/+.akk2dQ.b+VNYyJCyCJ
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Lm%2BVt%2Bd0%2B0dbJmm%2F%2B.akk2dQ.b%2BVNYyJCyCJ&input=%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%2C%5B4%2C-1%2C-2%5D%2C%5B-3%2C-4%2C10%5D%2C%5B1%2C2%2C10%5D&debug=0)

Direct translation of my [answer in Jelly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78820/48934).