# Natural Pi #2 - River

Tags: code-golf, string, math, pi, approximation

### Goal

Given an string with a train of hashes, calculate its total length and divide by the distance from start to finish.

### Simulation

**What are we simulating?** According to [this paper](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/271/5256/1710.abstract), the ratio of the length of a river to the distance between start and end is approximately Pi! (This may have been disproved empirically, but I could find the data and for this challenge we'll assume it is true).

**How are we simulating this?**

- Take a string input of whitespace and hashes
- Each hash will have two others adjacent to it

  - With the exception of the first and last hash which will have only 1
- Each character lies on a lattice point `(x, y)`
- `x` is the character's index in its line

  - eg `c` is the 4th character in `0123c567`
- `y` is the character's line number

  - eg `c` is on the 3rd line:

```
      0line
      1line
      2line
      3c...
```

- Sum the distances between adjacent hashes, call it `S`
- Take the distance between the first and last hashes, call it `D`
- Return `S/D`

[image]

### Specification

- **Input**

  - Flexible, take input in any of the standard ways (eg function parameter,STDIN) and in any standard format (eg String, Binary)
- **Output**

  - Flexible, give output in any of the standard ways (eg return, print)
  - White space, trailing and leading white space is acceptable
  - Accuracy, please provide at least 4 decimal places of accuracy (ie `3.1416`)
- **Scoring**

  - Shortest code wins!

### Test Cases

These are my approximations of the rivers. My approximations might be poor or these my be poor sample of the river population. Also, I did this calculations by hand; I could have miss calculated.

[Yellow River](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow_River#/media/File:Yellowrivermap.jpg)

```
        ### ####           
       #   #    #          
       #       #          #
       #       #         # 
       #       #        #  
      #         #      #   
##   #          # #####    
  ##  #          #         
    ##
```

```
1.6519
```

[Nile River](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nile#/media/File:River_Nile_map.svg)

```
         #     
         #     
          #    
           #   
           #   
          #    
         #     
        #      
        #  #   
        # # #  
         #  #  
            #  
          ##   
         #     
         #     
        #      
        #      
       #       
       #       
       #       
       #       
   #  #        
  # ##         
  #            
  #            
   #           
    #          
     #         
     #         
      #        
     #         
    #          
     #         
      #
```

```
1.5498
```

[Mississippi River](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mississippi_River#/media/File:Mississippiriver-new-01.png)

```
 ###            
#   #           
     #          
     #          
    #           
   #            
  #             
  #             
  #             
   #            
    #           
     #          
      #         
       #        
        #       
        #       
        #       
         #      
          #     
           #    
          #     
       ###      
      #         
       #        
      #         
     #          
    #           
    #           
    #           
    #           
     #          
      ##        
        #       
        #       
         ##     
           ##   
             ## 
               #
              # 
             #  
            #   
           #    
          #     
         #      
        #       
        #       
        #       
        #       
        #       
       #        
      #         
     #          
      #         
       #        
        ####    
            #   
             #
```

```
1.5257
```

#### TL;DR

These challenges are simulations of algorithms that only require nature and your brain (and maybe some re-usable resources) to approximate Pi. If you really need Pi during the zombie apocalypse, these methods don't [waste ammo](https://medium.com/the-physics-arxiv-blog/how-mathematicians-used-a-pump-action-shotgun-to-estimate-pi-c1eb776193ef#.eld2u7w76)! There are [nine challenges](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10035/43214) total.

Comment: They're called hashes on their own. "Hashtag" is just the term for an inline tag signified with `#<tag>`

Comment: I assume that the distance should be calculated using the Pythagorean theorem. Is this correct?

Comment: Also, can we take the input as a list of lines?

Comment: @Loovjo ^^ It can be, it is Euclidean geometry so however you want to calculate it is fine. ^ Yes, input is flexible.

Comment: Can the input be a matrix of zeros and ones?

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, that would be fine

Comment: Can we return a rational number?

Comment: Does the paper really say `pi`? The outputs look more similar to `pi/2`

Comment: @LuisMendo I believe it does say pi (but I don't have access to it anymore). Several [articles](https://www.theguardian.com/science/alexs-adventures-in-numberland/2015/mar/14/pi-day-2015-pi-rivers-truth-grime) about this paper say that the average sinuosity is 3.14. This particular article suggests that, empirically, the average sinuosity of rivers is around 1.94.

Comment: @NonlinearFruit Thanks. Then it's probably that the ASCII versions are not sinuous enough :)

Comment: @LegionMammal978 _Accuracy, please provide at least 4 decimal places of accuracy_

Comment: From these results, it seems the ratio is closer to Pi/2 than Pi.

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>48</s> <s>44</s> <s>42</s> <s>37</s> 33 bytes

*Quite a few bytes saved thanks to [rahnema1's idea (Octave answer)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104702/36398) of collapsing two convolutions into one*

```
t5BQ4B&vX^Z+*ssGt3Y6Z+1=*&fdwdYy/
```

This takes the input as a binary matrix, with `;` as row separator. `1` corresponds to hash and `0` to space.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@19i6hRo4qRWFhEXpa1VXOxeYhxpFqVtaKullpZSnhJZqf//f7SBAio0BEMYbahggA1ao@tBpQ2w68OhC68eBUMydBmSYZchhgtxmIzJszbEEgLo6gzRQ9QaFtr49eEKQ5xxgw3GAgA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#zVa7DsIwDNz5ik4MdCAnHovFgtg6ITHwUBED4gdAIL6@SJWKaBrbaZpIKENVXRzH57Ody76oHov1dr4eP/fnYz6534vH7LA85lhNxrfr63p4T6vNrjqZrL1Qr@aLzLgW2Tbtr3HbMVaiTYYAKwT4QueGzMndP4KDAXsfbEapYVu24zhkc@Na5egknk59UWPFweIBKAJvBUFrps0zuTPkUkHHmjiWIUSEQJ6HxutVeclRRuP0WxuGRfkOJKNG7V5al8IAlIvXp7JNXL919UPqGCT3L8V7Dxwh@dKyHQnX9RSDHz1/snJ8qnA4rnUXnwmhzQgI8UPwP5Q/JNNvetxPX@n1Y3lh8y@/Ar57SH6/QMShnK/O7Oj67Tmd/w5PVz/x@l/3Ld0/v98d5Qc).

[Here's](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#tZVBDoMgEEX3nmKSn5R9t249QnetSe9/CRsQlRm@CJiaGM0bGD9/Bly@w/PzmKbhtSxvJ/EC4G/IcblRtjDiLTgNmyiKYRRnI02eTtofPgyYLwb9OKT5dxW3ytVqk4XNw@FLnObGEhFkJMosElxmhhACS7A6pvLAfj0jwOW66vRoArlP0sIFgrRWkahOpUSQEd3ALmuMM2L0sDFVmZM8ocv0jvPDwHWX0xMNxALiUwtiDtdKZVbkntLWqESkN@lWJXvVjtqL0qgeXRXqR9zofle3ucav/CQL0KJw5huUj6LnUnOFCifRn1BftRv6fv91XZizWjj/AA) a format converter that takes inputs as 2D char arrays (again, with `;` as separator) and produces string representations of the corresponding binary matrices.

#### Explanation

This was fun! The code uses <s>three</s> two 2D-convolutions, each for a different purpose:

1. To detect vertical and horizontal neighbours, which contribute a distance of `1`, the required mask would be

   ```
   0 1 0
   1 0 1
   0 1 0
   ```

   But we only want each *pair* of neighbours to be detected once. So we take half the mask (and the last row of zeros can be removed):

   ```
   0 1 0
   1 0 0
   ```

   Similarly, to detect diagonal neighbours, which contribute a distance of `sqrt(2)`, the mask would be

   ```
   1 0 1
   0 0 0
   1 0 1
   ```

   but by the same reasoning as above it becomes

   ```
   1 0 1
   0 0 0
   ```

   If this mask is multiplied by `sqrt(2)` and added to the first, the two convolutions can be replaced by one convolution with the combined mask

   ```
   sqrt(2) 1  sqrt(2)
   1       0        0
   ```
2. Start and end points are, by definition, the points with only one neighbour. To detect them we convolve with

   ```
   1 1 1
   1 0 1
   1 1 1
   ```

   and see which points give `1` as result.

To produce the combined mask of item 1 it's shorter to generate its square and then take the square root. The mask in item 2 is a predefined literal.

```
t     % Take input matrix implicitly. Duplicate
5B    % 5 in binary: [1 0 1]
Q     % Add 1; [2 1 2]
4B    % 4 in binary: [1 0 0]
&v    % Concatenate vertically
X^    % Square root of each entry
Z+    % 2D convolution, maintaining size
*     % Multiply, to only keep results corresponding to 1 in the input
ss    % Sum of all matrix entries. This gives total distance
Gt    % Push input again. Duplicate
3Y6   % Predefined literal. This gives third mask
Z+    % 2D convolution, maintaining size
1=    % Values different than 1 are set to 0
*     % Multiply, to only keep results corresponding to 1 in the input
&f    % Push array of row indices and array of column indices of nonzeros
d     % Difference. This is the horizontal difference between start and end
wd    % Swap, difference. This is the vertical difference between start and end 
Yy    % Hypothenuse. This gives total distance in straight line
/     % Divide. Display implicitly
```

Comment: *Some* people used to say, that convolution is *the key to success*!

Answer (score 4):

## Octave, 99 bytes

```Octave
@(a)sum((c=conv2(a,[s=[q=2^.5 1 q];1 0 1;s],'same').*a)(:))/2/{[x y]=find(c<2&c>0),pdist([x y])}{2}
```

nearly same method as [MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/104685/edit) but here kernel of convolutions is

```Octave
1.41 ,  1  , 1.41
1    ,  0  , 1 
1.41 ,  1  , 1.41
```

that `sqrt(2) =1.41` is for diagonal neighbors  and `1`  is for direct neighbors  so when we sum values of the result over the river we get twice the real distance.
**ungolfed version**:

```Octave
a=logical([...
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]);
sq = sqrt(2);
kernel = [...
    sq ,  1  , sq
    1  ,  0  , 1 
    sq ,  1  , sq];
%2D convolution
c=conv2(a,kernel,'same').*a;
#river length
river_length = sum(c (:))/2;
#find start and end points
[x y]=find(c<2&c>0);
# distance between start and end points
dis = pdist([x y]);
result = river_length/ dis
```

Try (paste) it on [Octave Online](https://octave-online.net)

Comment: Your idea to lump the first two convolutions into one saved me a few bytes :)

Comment: `{[x y]=find(c<2&c>0),pdist([x y])}{2}` is so damn clever!!!

Comment: a good news is that we do not have restrictions of MATLAB!

Comment: @flawr Agreed. That should go to the [Octave golfing tips](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/49202/36398)!

Comment: @LuisMendo some entries included in tips

Comment: @rahnema1 Great! Since the tips question asks for one tip per answer, I suggest you move the `rows` part to a new answer. The rest of the current answer can be left as is, because it's all related to indexing in Octave

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 178

Input as a string with newlines *in rectangular form* : each line padded with spaces to the same length (as in the examples)

```js
r=>r.replace(/#/g,(c,i)=>([d=r.search`
`,-d,++d,-d,++d,-d,1,-1].map((d,j)=>r[i+d]==c&&(--n,s+=j&2?1:Math.SQRT2),n=1),n||(v=w,w=i)),w=s=0)&&s/2/Math.hypot(v%--d-w%d,~(v/d)-~(w/d))
```

*Less golfed*

```js
r=>(
  r.replace(/#/g, // exec the following for each '#' in the string
    (c,i) => // c: current char (=#), i: current position
    ( // check in 8 directions
      // note: d starts as the offset to next row, prev x position
      // and is incremented up to offset to next row, succ x position
      // note 2: there are 2 diagonal offsets, then 2 orthogonal offsets
      //         then other 2 diagonal, then 2 more orthogonal
      [d=r.search`\n`,-d, ++d,-d, ++d,-d, 1,-1].map( // for each offset
        (d,j) => // d: current offset, j: array position (0 to 7)
        r[i+d] == c && // if find a '#' at current offset ...
          ( 
            --n, // decrement n to check for 2 neighbors or just 1
            s += j & 2 ? 1 : Math.SQRT2 // add the right distance to s
          ),
      n = 1), // n starts at 1, will be -1 if 2 neighbors found, else 0
      // if n==0 we have found a start or end position, record it in v and w
      n || (v=w, w=i)
   ),
  w=s=0), // init s and w, no need to init v
  // at the end 
  // d is the length of a line + 1
  // s is twice the total length of the river
  // v and w can be used to find the x,y position of start and end
  s/2/Math.hypot(v%--d-w%d,~(v/d)-~(w/d))
)
```

**Test**

```js
F=
r=>r.replace(/#/g,(c,i)=>([d=r.search`\n`,-d,++d,-d,++d,-d,1,-1].map((d,j)=>r[i+d]==c&&(--n,s+=j&2?1:Math.SQRT2),n=1),n||(v=w,w=i)),w=s=0)&&s/2/Math.hypot(v%--d-w%d,~(v/d)-~(w/d))

Yellow=`        ### ####           
       #   #    #          
       #       #          #
       #       #         # 
       #       #        #  
      #         #      #   
##   #          # #####    
  ##  #          #         
    ##                     `

Nile=`         #     
         #     
          #    
           #   
           #   
          #    
         #     
        #      
        #  #   
        # # #  
         #  #  
            #  
          ##   
         #     
         #     
        #      
        #      
       #       
       #       
       #       
       #       
   #  #        
  # ##         
  #            
  #            
   #           
    #          
     #         
     #         
      #        
     #         
    #          
     #         
      #        `

Missi=` ###            
#   #           
     #          
     #          
    #           
   #            
  #             
  #             
  #             
   #            
    #           
     #          
      #         
       #        
        #       
        #       
        #       
         #      
          #     
           #    
          #     
       ###      
      #         
       #        
      #         
     #          
    #           
    #           
    #           
    #           
     #          
      ##        
        #       
        #       
         ##     
           ##   
             ## 
               #
              # 
             #  
            #   
           #    
          #     
         #      
        #       
        #       
        #       
        #       
        #       
       #        
      #         
     #          
      #         
       #        
        ####    
            #   
             #  `
console.log('Yellow River',F(Yellow))
console.log('Nile River',F(Nile))
console.log('Mississippi River',F(Missi))
```