# Press any key to continue

Tags: code-golf

Your task is to create a program that will display the following text, wait for the user to press a key (it is okay to ignore keys like `ctrl`, `alt`, `caps lock`, etc., as long as keys like `letters`, `numbers`, `symbols`, and `enter` are not ignored), and then terminate the program:

```
Press any key to continue...
```

Trailing newlines are allowed. The program must exit immediately after a key is pressed. Also, the program must be fairly portable (i.e no OS-specific headers or modules, runs outside of an IDE, etc.).

---

The prompt must be exactly as shown above, unless a trailing newline cannot be avoided.

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins. This is also my first code-golf question, so I apologize if I do not know the rules on PPCG.

Comment: Is the output text case sensitive? Would WinBatch `PAUSE` be a valid answer (ellipsis is spread from `...` to `. . .`)?

Comment: Also, you should stick your proposed challenges in the [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/60919) first so you can get feedback and flatten out the edge cases / loopholes.

Comment: I'm curious whether (for example) an empty C++ program is valid. Solves the task if ran in certain environments.

Comment: @TuukkaX It would not be valid.

Comment: Also I'd suggest waiting for a week or 2 before accepting any answer

Comment: I agree with @KritixiLithos ... This challenge is code-golf, and the 89-byte Processing solution is not the shortest answer.

Comment: @JungHwanMin In fact it is the most verbose of all the answers :/

Comment: Most language's `pause` functions are probably insensitive to keys like Caps-Lock or Control (pressed on its own). Maybe you should clarify if the program is allowed not to notice those keys

Comment: @JungHwanMin It has been changed to the MATL answer, which is the shortest (valid) answer as yet.

Comment: You should wait for a few weeks before accepting an answer, as countless others have advised you (yet you've chosen to ignore their advice)

Comment: Also, I think you should state that you should wait for a _character to be typed_ rather than a _key to be pressed_, as most solutions will rely on something along the lines of `getch()`, which doesn't take into account control characters.

Comment: @JungHwanMin I agree with others. Please wait to accept a solution until entries have stopped rolling in. I really don't enjoy riding the Reputation Roller Coaster

Comment: Should I just take this question down?

Comment: @ckjbgames No, why? Just wait some days before accepting an answer definitively. And edit the challeng text to include the information that control keys can be missed by the program

Comment: Keys like `Alt`, `Ctrl`, `Shift` are called _modifier keys_. What you probably want is to allow ignoring modifier keys (but not require it) and to require to react to all non-modifier keys.

Comment: You probably should mention "space" key specially because it doesn't seem to fall into any listed category.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### SmallBasic, <s>18</s> 17 bytes

- Version 2.0

17 bytes

```
TextWindow.Show()
```

- Version 1.0

18 bytes

```
TextWindow.Pause()
```

Comment: Couldn't you also just do `TextWindow.Show()`? Based on [this site](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16303.small-basic-curriculum-lesson-1-2-statements-properties-and-operations.aspx) that should have the same effect.

Answer (score 20):

### Batch, 46 bytes

```
@echo Press any key to continue...
@pause>nul
```

Because `pause`'s output contains a space before each `.`.

Comment: Nice redirect. Could you also send the output to, say, `x`? Then a file `x` would be created that holds the text `Press any key to continue . . .`. Saves 2 bytes, but I'm not sure if that goes against this challenge or any standard loopholes.

Comment: I'm on choice.exe-free system since a while, but I have a feeling `@choice /n /m Press any key to continue...` was also possible some decades ago.

Comment: Choice has default values as J and N, so the program would only go on when  J or N are pressed if I remember correctly.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 Also, the default value is localized. For example, to me `choice` is equivalent to `choice /c SN` (for `sim` (yes) and `não` (no) in Portuguese).

Comment: Ah, you are right, @geisterfurz007. Now I remember how silly looked my batch files having the entire alphabet enumerated. Ok, then this was a dead idea.

Answer (score 15):

## HTML + JavaScript (ES6), 36 + 25 = 61 bytes

You can't really exit a JavaScript program, so clearing the webpage is the best I can think of.

```js
onkeyup=_=>a.innerHTML=''
```

```html
<a id=a>Press any key to continue...
```

---

## HTML + JavaScript (ES6), 33 + 28 = 61 bytes

Alternate solution [suggested by @LarsW](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/107709/press-any-key-to-continue/107750?noredirect=1#comment262098_107750) that redirects to `about:blank`.

```js
onkeyup=_=>location='about:blank'
```

```html
Press any key to continue...
```

---

## HTML/JavaScript, 60 bytes

Another awesome solution [by @Ismael Miguel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/107709/press-any-key-to-continue/107750?noredirect=1#comment262407_107750) that doesn't use standalone JS. 1 byte saved!

```html
<html onkeyup=this.innerHTML=''>Press any key to continue...
```

---

## HTML + JavaScript (ES6), 26 + 28 = 54 bytes

Yet another solution [by @George Reith](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/107709/press-any-key-to-continue/107750?noredirect=1#comment262736_107750) making use of document writes.

```js
onkeyup=_=>document.open()
```

```html
Press any key to continue...
```

## HTML + JavaScript (ES7), 23 + 28 = 51 bytes

Same program using the [proposed ES7 bind operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bind-operator):

```js
onkeyup=::document.open
```

```html
Press any key to continue...
```

---

As most of these solutions are not my own, do a courtesy and vote them up in the comments!

Comment: Perhaps a redirect to `about:blank`?

Comment: 36 + 25 is 61 or am I missing something?

Comment: @LarsW That would add more bytes

Comment: @ckjbgames yeah, but it would exit the 'program' in a better way, IMO

Comment: @LarsW Still, this is code golf, so we save bytes :)

Comment: @LarsW, ckjbgames Well, what are the chances? You never know until you write it! ;)

Comment: @darrylyeo It turn out that the two snippets are the same length. :)

Comment: `<html onkeyup=this.innerHTML=''>Press any key to continue...` <-- 60 bytes. Try it on https://jsfiddle.net/xhb69401/ (it works with both `<html>` and `<body>`)

Comment: Shorter way to clear the document and doesn't need anchor. `onkeyup=_=>document.open()` with  `Press any key to continue...` for a grand total of 54 bytes.

Comment: Brilliant! You're all blowing my own solution out of the water.

Comment: Also with the es-next proposed bind operator it could be reduced to `onkeyup=::document.open`.

Answer (score 14):

## MATL, 35 bytes

```
'Press any key to continue...'D0$Y.
```

**Explanation**

```
'Press any key to continue...'      % String literal
D                                   % Display the string (has trailing newline)
0$Y.                                % Pause until the user presses any key
```

Comment: @LuisMendo Ah good catch

Comment: On the other hand, `Y.` doesn't either. Maybe the OP should clarify. Keys like Control and Caps-lock will fail in most of the solutions

Comment: @LuisMendo It is fine to miss control keys, caps lock, etc.

Comment: @LuisMendo Wouldn't your modification require an enter key? Or maybe I'm mis-remembering it

Comment: @Suever Oh, of course! Enter is required

Comment: Still the best.

Comment: @ckjbgames What about [this one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/107791/51939)?

Comment: @ckjbgames And that is precisely why it is recommended to wait *weeks* before accepting an answer.

Answer (score 11):

## TI-Basic, 55 bytes

Basically, it loops until a key is pressed. Too bad lowercase letters are two bytes each in TI-Basic...

```
Disp "Press any","key to continuesin(
Repeat getKey
End
```

P.S. See the comment by @GoldenRatio for the explanation as to how this works. It's genius!

Comment: First of all, your byte count is currently off, that is actually 55 bytes (just made a program on TI-84+ and tested). Second, this technically isn't valid, because it doesn't display Press any key to continue... and instead it cuts to 15 chars plus ... Instead, preserving byte count, make it two disp commands. `:Disp "Press any` (don't forget : in your code, it counts) and `Disp "key to continuesin(` (The sin forces a ... in 1 byte to make up for the new line and disp, and this saves a space between any and key)

Comment: Beat me to this, first language I thought of.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @GoldenRatio, I guess I was thinking `getKey` was 2 bytes when it's actually 1. I suppose with `Text(` or `Output(` you could fit it all on one line. But, your suggestion is better. I didn't think about using the implicit ellipsis at the end of a line. Thanks again, I'll edit that now.

Comment: Thx for updating it, and I guess using disp with a comma has a good reason finally, since it never saved bytes. I usually put them on seperate lines because of my tendency to hit the clear button :D. Also, is there any official method of how to score the size? By this I mean, should the 9 bytes I did _not_ count for a program name count? And should the 1 byte for the start colon that cannot be deleted count? I did mark that as 0 bytes, because for finding space I'm used to subtracting 10 for program size, but maybe the colon should count.

Comment: No, basically if you make a completely empty program it counts for 0 bytes, then you start from there. That would be like counting the filename of a source file. Also, the beginning colon is just for show and is not actually a part of the program. In fact, every newline automatically shows a colon in the editor on the calculator, but again, these are just for show (try cemetech sourcecoder to see what I mean). Last, the bytecount is the same whether we split the `Disp` over two lines or not (but, it is not always this way).

Answer (score 8):

## Bash, <s>46</s> <s>43</s> 42 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @DigitalTrauma*

```
read -rn1 -p"Press any key to continue..."
```

Uses the `read` built-in. `-r` makes sure it doesn't allow the user to input escapes. `-n 1` allows just one character. `-p` is the prompt

Comment: Doesn't continue until I hit a <cr>

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson I believe that can happen if your bash does not support `-n 1` . It works without hitting enter for me however (v3.2.57) and on my debain machine (v4.3.30)

Comment: Also doesn't work if I type a quote (")

Comment: I have #bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.46(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) on Ubuntu 16:04

Comment: Does work OK if I put the line in a file (anykey.sh) and run that.  Works fine too even if I remove the space between "-rn" and "1".

Comment: `-rn1` saves 1 byte

Answer (score 8):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>51</s> 50 bytes (Thanks @villou24)

```hs
main=putStr"Press any key to continue...">>getChar
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@5@bmJlnW1BaElxSpBRQlFpcrJCYV6mQnVqpUJKvkJyfV5KZV5qqp6enZGeXnlrinJFY9P8/AA)

Comment: That waits for enter. You can use `getChar` instead.

Comment: You can save a byte by removing the space between `putStr` and the string.

Comment: Let the answerer edit his own post, @ckjbgames , don't do it for him

Answer (score 5):

## Octave / MATLAB, 42 bytes

```
disp('Press any key to continue...');pause
```

Comment: I upvoted this answer a month ago, assuming it was optimal... But you've been [outgolfed](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111978/31516) :)

Answer (score 4):

## Processing, <s>89</s> 81 bytes

```processing
void setup(){print("Press any key to continue...");}void draw(){if(key>0)exit();}
```

#### Explanation

```processing
void setup(){print("Press any key to continue...");}
```

This is required since I am using more than one function in my program. Anything inside `setup()` gets called, in this case the string `"Press any key to continue..."`.

```processing
if(key>0)exit();
```

Checks if `key` (`key` will always contain the int value of the last key pressed) is more than `0` (ie not a null byte). If the condition is satisfied, then the program exits.

```processing
void draw(){}
```

`draw()` ensures that that the program will always keep looking for a key instead of stopping once the program starts.

(That feel when a builtin in a Java-like language is still verbose...)

Comment: I don't *really* know Processing, but I think you should be able to replace `void steup(){...}` with `static{...}`

Comment: @Pavel Nope, doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

### Bash <s>48</s> <s>44</s> 42 bytes

```
read -rn1 -p"Press any key to continue..."
```

@mame98 Thanks for saving 4 bytes.

@RaisingAgent Thanks for saving 2 bytes.

Comment: You can improve this by adding up the flags, like `read -srn1 -p".."` and remove the last space in the promt quote. Also, I'm not sure if you need the 's' flag

Comment: remove the last space in the quotes `_` & `-s`

Comment: @RaisingAgent Thanks, updated :)

Answer (score 4):

## QBasic ([QB64](http://qb64.net)), 37 (42?) bytes

Unfortunately, QBasic's built-in end-of-program prompt doesn't have the ellipsis, so we'll have to print it ourselves:

```
?"Press any key to continue..."
SLEEP
```

(`SLEEP` without an argument waits until a keypress.)

This code does what the question literally asks for, but it doesn't seem like it fits the spirit of the question because, of course, QBasic then displays "Press any key to continue" and waits for a keypress before returning to the IDE. Here's one that goes straight to the IDE, for +5 bytes:

```
?"Press any key to continue..."
SLEEP
STOP
```

`STOP` is a debugging statement. In regular QBasic, it sets a breakpoint: execution halts and we return to the IDE, but execution can be resumed again with F5. It's unclear whether that would count as the program "exiting." However, I'm using the QB64 emulator, which can't do breakpoints. Upon encountering `STOP`, it simply halts--returning straight to the IDE without the redundant "Press any key" message.

Comment: Oddly enough, the 'Press any key to continue' also shows up when executing a standalone QB64 exe. I tried to use `LOCATE` to just print the dots after it, but QBasic clears the entire bottom row when it prints this message...

Answer (score 4):

## Pascal, <s>75</s> 65 bytes

This was tested with the Free Pascal Compiler, version 3.0.0.
It may work with TurboPascal 7 or newer.

```
uses Crt;begin write('Press any key to continue...');readkey;end.
```

Sadly, I can't replace `readkey` with `readln` since the challenge requires that **any** key be accepted.

---

I've tested this code on http://rextester.com/l/pascal_online_compiler, with and without supplying an input.
As expected, the program is terminated after 10s, since it sits waiting for a keypress that never happens.

---

Thanks to [@manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork) for saving me 10 bytes by proving me wrong, and showing that I don't need the `program _;`.

Comment: Neither FreePascal nor TurboPascal requires the use of `program` keyword. (Actually I never met such ancient implementation that did.)

Comment: @manatwork I tried it without `program` and it complained. Also, I sometimes use TurboPascal. That one requires (notice: **requires**) the `program` there. If you know any place I can test where it runs without the `program`, I will remove it. I hate having it there. And that `uses Crt;`.

Comment: I don't get you. It works fine including the rextester service you linked. In my command line: http://pastebin.com/pVr9dqxd

Comment: @manatwork You're right. I know why it complained: I wrote `program;` instead of actually removing that bit. Thanks for alerting me to that.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, 110 bytes

```
import curses as c
s=c.initscr()
c.cbreak()
s.addstr(0,0,'Press any key to continue...')
while not s.getch():1
```

Comment: Cutting it down to 98 bytes (current Python 3): `from curses import*
s=initscr()
raw()
s.addstr('Press any key to continue...')
while 0>s.getch():1`

Answer (score 4):

## Scratch, 81 bytes

[image]

```
when gf clicked
say [Press any key to continue...
wait until <key [any v] pressed
```

([Scratchblocks link](http://scratchblocks.github.io/#when%20gf%20clicked%0Asay%20%5BPress%20any%20key%20to%20continue...%0Await%20until%20%3Ckey%20%5Bany%20v%5D%20pressed))

If you wanted it to stop the *entire* program when you pressed a key (including other threads) you'd have to add a `stop all`. If you want to get rid of the say dialog you need an empty `say` block (`stop all` works as well).

Convenient that Scratch has a builtin for this!

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby (2.3) (+ Batch), <s>52</s> <s>55</s> <s>54</s> <s>53</s> 46 bytes

Now 46 bytes thanks to Alexis Andersen.

Note: Tested on Windows, might not work if there is no `pause` command.

```
puts"Press any key to continue...";`pause>nul`
```

## Explanation

`Puts` the required text:

```
puts"Press any key to continue..."
```

End the line:

```
;
```

Run the Batch `pause` command and pipe output to `nul`:

```
`pause>nul`
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to PPCG.  I see that you have a list of edits in the body of your submission.  While this may be customary on other sites, since anyone can see the edit history of a post, we generally leave the history of the post out of the body (aside from the strike throughs for byte counts).  This seems like a good first golf and I hope you have fun here.

Comment: @WheatWizard Thanks, should I leave the edits there or remove them?

Comment: I think that it makes for a much more readable answer if you remove them and I would personally recommend doing so.

Comment: you can shorten that by replacing system with backticks: ` `pause>nul` ` or even shorter, just use gets (also, there's no good way to include a backtick in a code block in a comment)

Comment: @AlexisAndersen doesn't `gets` wait for enter, and not just any key?

Comment: *facepalm* yes, you're right. The backticks are still valid though

Comment: I think you could consume `pause`'s output with assignment: ``x=`pause` ``.

Answer (score 3):

### R, 56 bytes

```
cat('Press any key to continue...');keypress::keypress()
```

This works in Linux and OSX terminals.

Answer (score 3):

## Java, 127 bytes

```java
class P{public static void main(String[]a)throws Exception{System.out.print("Press any key to continue...");System.in.read();}}
```

Note: [the console must be set to raw mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1066318/) in order for this to work.

Comment: Then I'm afraid _your code_ should set the console so, like [original.legin](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64287/original-legin)'s [Perl solution](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/107752) does.

Comment: @manatwork `Also, the program must be fairly portable (i.e no OS-specific headers or modules, runs outside of an IDE, etc.)` if you follow that SO link there is no OS-independent way to do this. Meaning, the answer you linked is equally as valid as this one.

Answer (score 3):

## SmileBASIC, 52 bytes

```
?"Press any key to continue...
WHILE""==INKEY$()WEND
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 62 bytes

```
EventHandler["Press any key to continue...","KeyDown":>Exit[]]
```

**Explanation**

```
EventHandler["Press any key to continue...","KeyDown":>Exit[]]
EventHandler[                                                ]  (* Create a new EventHandler *)
             "Press any key to continue..."                     (* Print the dialog text *)
                                            "KeyDown":>Exit[]   (* When a key is pressed down, exit *)
```

Answer (score 2):

## SmileBASIC, 55 bytes

```
?"Press any key to continue..."@L IF INKEY$()!=""GOTO@L
```

Explained:

```
?"Press any key to continue..."  '? means PRINT
@L                               'start of loop
IF INKEY$()!="" GOTO @L          'if no key pressed goto @L
```

Comment: `WHILE""==INKEY$()WEND` is smaller

Answer (score 2):

## **Python 3, 65 bytes**

Requires the Windows version of Python.

```
from msvcrt import*
print("Press any key to continue...")
getch()
```

msvcrt.getch() doesn't wait for the enter key to be pressed like input(), it returns the first key pressed.

Python Docs for msvcrt.getch():
https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.getch

Thanks to @Fliptack for saving some bytes

Comment: This answer is invalid without an `import msvcrt` somewhere

Comment: As this is code-golf you should remove the comments from your code. Also, using `from msvcrt import*` [appears to be 1 byte shorter](https://ethproductions.github.io/bytes/?e=utf-8&t=from%20msvcrt%20import%2A%0Aprint%28%22Press%20any%20key%20to%20continue%2E%2E%2E%22%29%0Agetch%28%29)

Comment: cool, thx @FlitTack

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2/3 POSIX, 85 bytes

```
import sys,tty
print('Press any key to continue...')
tty.setraw(1)
sys.stdin.read(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Node.js, <s>102</s> <s>101</s> 99 bytes

```js
with(process)stdout.write('Press any key to continue...'),s=stdin,s.setRawMode(1),s.on('data',exit)
```

Comment: Not much gain, just 1 character shorter with `with`: http://pastebin.com/BhrAyq2K

Comment: @manatwork Nice one! First time `with` has saved me bytes (or byte)

Comment: Now you can remove the curly brackets and replace line breaks with commas for 2 more bytes.

Comment: Also if I'm not mistaken, `stdout.write\`Press any key to continue...\`` will save 2 bytes in ES6.

Comment: @darrylyeo Commas work thats awesome thanks! Unfortunately a tagged template literal can't be used here as it actually passes in an array and `process.stdout.write` doesn't do implicit conversions to string (it just errors).

Comment: Nice. Yeah, I suspected that might be the case.

Comment: Shouldn't console.log be shorter?

Comment: @MatthewRoh "The prompt must be exactly as shown above, unless a trailing newline cannot be avoided." Because this doesn't add a trailing newline and `console.log` does I can't use it.

Comment: Wait, now they are allowing trailing newlines.

Answer (score 2):

## Sinclair ZX81/Timex TS1000 BASIC: Method 1 approximately 41 bytes

```
1 PRINT "PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE..."
2 GOTO (INKEY$<>"")+VAL "2"
```

### Method 2 approximately 38 BYTES

```
1 PRINT "PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE..."
2 PAUSE VAL "4E4"
```

I prefer method 1 as on the ZX81, there is a screen flicker when `PAUSE` is called, and if you want long enough (providing the ZX81 doesn't overheat or crash) the pause will eventually come to an end, whereas method 1 is stuck in an infinite loop until a key is pressed, and no screen flicker.

I'll work out the correct number of bytes used later when I have the right bit of BASIC that will tell me. By the way, using VAL "x" instead of the number saves valuable RAM on a ZX81 (I think that this is the same for the ZX Spectrum as well).

Comment: Both methods will work on the Sinclair ZX Spectrum as well, the advantage being that the Spectrum has upper and lower case letters, whereas the ZX81 does not by default (and doesn't have a single quote either as a standard character).

Comment: Method 2 on the Sinclair ZX Spectrum could be condensed to `1 PRINT "Press any key to continue...": PAUSE 4e4`

Comment: `PAUSE 0` pauses for ever.

Comment: Yes I've not programmed in Sinclair Spectrum BASIC for so long that I forgot about that. `PAUSE 0` in ZX81 BASIC does not pause forever.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl 5, 79 bytes

```
system "stty cbreak";$|=1;print "Press any key to continue...";read(STDIN,$a,1)
```

used as:

```
perl -e 'system "stty cbreak";$|=1;print "Press any key to continue...";read(STDIN,$a,1)'
```

No prizes of course. I'm sure some perl person will have a better way.

(89 bytes if the interpreter invocation as well needs to be included in the count)

Comment: @Pavel, he counted `system` in his bytecount, so I don't know what you meant with that comment.

Comment: @original.legin I think Perl won't do much better than this. A few bytes you can golf still: `$|=1` isn't necessary, you have a space after `print`, you can drop the parenthesis around the arguments of `read`, you can use backticks instead of system, and finally, `print` returns 1, so you can use it instead of the litteral `1` in the call to `read`. So in the end, we get: `perl -e '\`stty cbreak\`;read STDIN,$a,print"Press any key to continue..."'`

Comment: @Dada You can also shave off 2 bytes with `say`, although I think this approach fails the "portable" requirement. The best portable solution I can find is `perl -MTerm::ReadKey -E'say"Press any key to continue...";ReadMode 3;ReadKey'` (52 bytes + 16 bytes for `-MTerm::ReadKey<space>`). Be careful, this will screw up your terminal unless you restore the read mode at the end with `ReadMode 1`.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Indeed, I didn't see that requirement about portability. About `say`, I tend not to use it anymore (I agree mostly with [this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7539/55508) meta post). Now back to a short code, `IO::Prompt` will be shorter than `Term::ReadKey` (40 + 13 = 53 bytes) : `perl -MIO::Prompt -e 'prompt"Press any key to continue... ",-1'`. And as it happens, it's even shorter than what I suggested in my previous comment.

Comment: @Dada I can see both sides of the `-E` argument. The last time I checked, though, J B's answer had been uncontested for four years, so that's what I've followed. Maybe I need to revisit it again. As for IO::Prompt, good find! Although it doesn't work on my Strawberry 5.20.2 on Windows, while Term::ReadKey does.

Comment: I don't think this works with perl on my windows box.  Was it meant to be portable?

Answer (score 1):

## [8th](http://8th-dev.com/), 47 bytes

```
"Press any key to continue..." . cr con:key bye
```

This program ignores keys like ctrl, alt, caps lock. Quits with keys like letters, numbers, symbols, and enter.

**Explanation**

```
"Press any key to continue..." . cr \ Print message 
con:key                             \ Wait for key input from console  
bye                                 \ Quit program
```

Comment: On Windows only you can save 3 bytes omitting `cr `

Answer (score 1):

#### PHP, 73 bytes

```
echo"Press any key to continue...";$h=fopen("php://stdin","r");fgets($h);
```

Run it in the PHP interactive shell (`php -a`)

Comment: “The program must exit immediately after a key is pressed.” – This waits until Enter or blackout…

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 101 bytes

```
using C=System.Console;class P{static void Main(){C.Write("Press any key to continue...");C.Read();}}
```

Tested on Linux, should run on any system having the .NET libraries and the Common Language Runtime.

Ungolfed program:

```
using C = System.Console; // creating a shorter alias for the System.Console class

class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        C.Write("Press any key to continue...");    // prints the message
        C.Read();   // waits for key press
    }
}
```

CTRL, ALT, SHIFT are ignored. The pressed key will be echoed on screen if printable.

Echo can be disabled by replacing *C.Read()* with *C.ReadKey(0<1)* at the cost of 6 more bytes.

Answer (score 1):

### C#, 29 bytes

```
class P{static void Main(){}}
```

Not sure if this is considered valid because it prints:

> Press any key to continue . . .

But there is a [Batch](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/107804/38550) answer that prints this as well.

Answer (score 1):

## SmallBasic 17 bytes

```
TextWindow.Show()
```

I had this answer before the accepted answer added it to their answer by the way. (To avoid unjust flags)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53693/discussion-on-answer-by-christopher-peart-press-any-key-to-continue).

Answer (score 1):

## Forth (gforth), 39 bytes

```
." Press any key to continue..."key bye
```

(Yes, there is already an 8th solution but this is shorter)

Answer (score 0):

## HTML + Javascript, 58 bytes

```html
<html onkeyup=document.open('')>Press any key to continue.
```

Answer (score 0):

## MATLAB, 41 bytes

or it could be **Octave, 40 bytes.**

This is quite similar to the [obvious approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/107714/31516) posted by Suever, but is **one glorious byte shorter**.

```
disp 'Press any key to continue...'
pause
```

or in Octave:

```
disp"Press any key to continue..."
pause
```

A little known and little used feature of both [MATLAB](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111979/31516) and [Octave](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111980/31516) is that most builtin functions can be called without parentheses, in which case they will treat whatever follows it as a string (as long as it doesn't contain spaces).

For instance:

```
nnz PPCG
ans = 4

size PPCG
ans = 1  4

str2num 12
ans = 12
```

Now, if the input is a word with multiple words, then we need the quotation marks, so `disp('Press any key to continue...')` is reduced to `disp 'Press any key to continue...'`, saving one byte. Instead of the semicolon separating the `disp` call and the `pause`, we now separate them using a linefeed.

Answer (score 0):

## C64Mini/C64 BASIC (also VIC-20 BASIC) 52 tokenized BASIC bytes

```
 0?"PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE...":POKE198,0:WAIT198,1
```

The `?` is short-hand for `PRINT`; thereafter, `POKE 198,0` will clear the keyboard buffer, whilst `WAIT 198,1` will wait until the keyboard buffer has something in it again.

Because the keyboard buffer isn't cleared whatever key is struck when the program executes is displayed. You may tidy this up with another 4 BASIC tokens by adding `:GETA$` to the end of line zero.

The screen shot shows the VIC-20 in action, which by default only has a 22 column display [source](http://www.zimmers.net/cbmpics/cbm/vic/memorymap.txt)

[image: VIC-20 "Press any key to continue" program]