# How to swap elements in a vector using an anonymous function in Octave?

Tags: code-golf, array, tips, octave

Swapping two elements in a vector/matrix is very simple in Octave:

```
x='abcde';
x([4,1])=x([1,4])
x = 
   dbcae
```

Unfortunately, I have yet to find a way to do this inside an anonymous function. While the function below is syntactically correct, it only gives back the two elements that are swapped, not the entire `x` vector:

```
f=@(x)(x([4,1])=x([1,4]))
f(x)
ans = 
     ad
```

Is there a way to achieve the desired behavior using anonymous functions in a golfy way? Can several elements be swapped this way using an anonymous function?

I *could* create an indexing vector: `f=@(x)x([4,2,3,1,5])`, but creating such a vector dynamically will likely take a lot of bytes too.

Comment: [Relevant meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1724/31516).

Answer (score 21):

## Argument List

```
f=@(x,y=x([4 1])=x([1 4]))x;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQaNCp9K2QiPaRMEwVhPEMFQwidXUrLD@n5hXrKGUmJScoqT5HwA)

Comment: Wait _what_? I never knew this was possible in Octave. This opens up so many new techniques....

Comment: What in the...?

Comment: Please post this in the Tips for Octave question! With this technique, you can basically do everything in the argument list, so you never need to choose between a 'full' and anonymous function again. I'm shocked.

Comment: Amazing. BTW, you can remove the final `;` for the purposes of byte count

Comment: Thanks to all .@Sanchises It seems that Octave is a shocking language. Be careful! It is added to tips.

Comment: @LuisMendo, you can't actually. Not sure why though... [Try it](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0Kn0rZCI9pEwTBWE8QwVDCJ1dSs@J@moZSYlJyipPkfAA).

Comment: @StewieGriffin Just move the `;` to the footer; [see here](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0Kn0rZCI9pEwTBWE8QwVDCJ1dSs@G@tkKahlJiUnKKk@R8A)

Comment: That feels like cheating... I know it's pretty much the same as moving the `f=...` to the header. The difference is that the function would still work with `ans('abc')` if we remove `f=...`, but it's a syntax error without the `;`.

Comment: @StewieGriffin and LuisMendo  I think it is a bug. It can be used in arrayfun,cellfun...

Answer (score 11):

## Be `eval`

```
f=@(x)eval"x([4 1])=x([1 4])"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0IztSwxR6lCI9pEwTBW0xbIMFQwidVU@l9hq56YlJySqm7NlQZU9h8A)

---

In Matlab the parentheses cannot be omitted:

```
f=@(x)eval('x([4 1])=x([1 4])')
```

Comment: Only on PPCG is `eval` the answer :-)

Comment: Do you want to add [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/163103/31516) to the Octave tips question? `for` loop inside an anonymous function using `eval` saved a lot of bytes there, and can probably do it on many other challenges too,,,

Comment: Not sure if it is ever golfier, but I suppose you can do it even without anonymous function: `s='x([1 4])=x([4 1])';eval(s)` -- I suppose this is mostly interesting if you already made a function to do eval with minimal chars.

Comment: @StewieGriffin I think you should add it. Thanks for asking!

Comment: [Added](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/163131/31516) :)

Comment: I think this answer is the only one thusfar that is both valid Octave and Matlab.

Comment: @StewieGriffin Thanks! Now it's even _eviller_

Comment: Are you sure about the parentheses in Matlab? I thought a single space and apostrophes was enough. I might be wrong though...

Comment: I _think_ it should work if you use commas as the delimiter at least..?

Answer (score 8):

### Cell array

One option is to use a cell array, like this:

```
f=@(x){x([1,4])=x([4,1]);x}{2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0KzukIj2lDHJFbTFsgw0TGM1bSuqK02qv2fpqGemJSckqqu@R8A)

Comment: Nice one! Reminds me of [this trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104753/36398)