# split and capitalize

Tags: code-golf, string

## Challenge :

Given a string split at specific positions and capitalize the first character of the given word. Capitalize the first word's first char if and only if it was already capitalized

## Input :

A string `s` and a character `c`.

## Ouput :

The string with each occurrence of `c` replaced with the first char capitalized

## Examples :

```
STRING(s)             CHARACTER(c)  RESULT
Hello_world           _             HelloWorld
me,no,like            ,             meNoLike
you-got-it            -             youGotIt
Am^I^clear            ^             AmIClear
go!full!caps          !             goFullCaps
weird&but&tRue        &             weirdButTRue
ProbleM1fixed1no      1             ProbleMFixedNo
!prob!!lem!s!Olved!!  !             ProbLemSOlved
```

---

## Note :

- Given input will always be valid. i.e : The first will always be a string with at least one instance of the character to replace at. The second will always will be a single character.
- The length of the input string will be greater 4.
- There will be at least one occurrence of the character to split at.
- The input is guaranteed to contain only letters and the separator (Thanks @Arnauld)
- Separator is anything that is not an alphabet (a-z / A-Z) (suggested by @Dennis)

---

## Winning criteria :

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code in bytes for each language wins.

---

1. Thanks to @JonathanAllan for pointing out two mistakes.

Comment: Tips when creating test cases: Make each one cover at least one corner case. All your test cases are basically identical (maybe except the one with `1`). Try to think about how solutions might fail, and make a test case for such situations. Some examples: Letters as separators, the separator being the last character, consecutive separators and so on. There's no need to have many test cases that doesn't test different things.

Comment: You're missing a delimiter in the last test case - there should be a ! there. I would edit it myself, but there's not enough characters for me to do it.

Comment: Can it be `123 | 2 => 13`?

Comment: @l4m2 : If it helps you Yes otherwise general rule so far is that the test case will have at least one alphabet

Comment: I've downvoted this due to the multiple changes to the spec. On a sidenote, you need to make mention a _lot_ sooner than the last test case that the string may contain 2 or more consecutive "separators" and that we are not guaranteed that a letter will always follow a "separator".

Comment: @Shaggy : I can't stop you from down-voting so :( . Also The test case was suggested by Dennis and frankly I don't see a problem with where it is. You are supposed to read the test case. Tell me if there is a problem and then it can be changed.

Comment: Not that it matters, but I didn't suggest any test cases.

Comment: @Dennis : I'm pretty sure it was you , if not then StewieGriffin ? I don't know, you removed all comments

Comment: I looked it up: Stewie didn't suggest any test cases, but he asked whether the first or last character could be a separator and whether there could be consecutive separators. In the future, please consider using the sandbox to get all these details sorted out before going live. It's frustrating to get your answer invalidated because of changes in the specification. The most surprising of all is the restriction to take the character as input, even if the program doesn't need it. That makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Dennis : I didn't add that and didn't intend to. See the Scala answer for clarification on that. (If you think it is not required I could removed it) but i'm guessing that's gonna get me more down-votes

Comment: Yes, I've seen the Scala answer. If an answer surprises you by not requiring one of the inputs, just let it be, don't add extra rules to the challenge to invalidate the answer. (That's my opinion, not a rule.) Improving your challenge by removing a superfluous restriction shouldn't earn you any downvotes. I'm sure the affected answerers would be happy to save a few bytes.

Comment: @Dennis : So I should change this ?

Comment: I think so, yes.

Comment: @Dennis : Okat done.

Comment: @Dennis : I updated the description just for you :)

Comment: Can we have a test-case with separator `.`, I can imagine some string splitting functions struggling with that one.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 63 bytes

```python
lambda s,c:''.join(map(min,s,s[0]+s.title()[1:])).replace(c,'')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc@9TsMwFIbhmVyFvcS2cCIitkgd2GBAINbSVKlzUgzHP7IdSq8@xJj1eXU@6fhr@nD2fp3JjryvOJrTNJIoVc9Y@@m05Wb03Ggro4z7u8NtbJNOCFzsu/4gRBvA46iAK8mYWGcXtmOiiLaEVxVnj4DojhcXcGKSsCMTclMD0jqJ@gsyyoJXtzRnlxqdMjYFH8zwNCiEMWQcCp4dnRdEqkYfM9PCF9Bhqk9LqtPb8rdcl/Aa3AnhuZv1D0yddTl1JVG/NUoRDI30Bb9hov@LVSX66sYHbROfeX5KiPUX)

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>58</s> 56 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @l4m2 / @Downgoat*

Takes input in currying syntax `(s)(c)`.

```javascript
s=>c=>s.replace(u=/./g,x=>u=x==c?'':u?x:x.toUpperCase())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc9La8JAFIbhfX@Fk4UmkAtuhYlYwVawtvRCd0qcnIS0k5wwF01/fToTrG3Hs3154Dsf2TGTTFStihrMoS9oL2nKaCpjAS3PGPiaJnFShh1NNe0oZfPJZKbn3ayLFb61LYhlJsEPgp5hI5FDzLH0C9@7B85xf0LBcy/wvb0XBKPLJclo6O823ziyhrDBkFefYGH4D1pZwxY3prruC3VUoooqZV105Uy/Q7VWrlvUu/WOcciEdbsrt6jXS1tdVyIpNOeEZa20kvyVxpW4MnlpqitPUIl8fNBqrJ718OX41xo59FutXk117ZPAA4eHaVF1kE8btHr6o40995XNW3Q1aU0mhENNJHnkR8gJuWw/6w3UL0PqvwE)

#### Commented

```javascript
s => c =>                  // given s and c
  s.replace(u = /./g, x => // initialize u to a RegExp; replace each character x in s with,
    u =                    // and update u to:
      x == c ?             //   if x is the separator:
        ''                 //     an empty string
      :                    //   else:
        u ?                //     if u is not an empty string:
          x                //       x unchanged
        :                  //     else:
          x.toUpperCase()  //       x capitalized
  )                        // end of replace()
```

Comment: consolation 56 bytes for ``s=>c=>s.replace(RegExp(c+".","g"),m=>m[1].toUpperCase())``, since it doesn't work for special regex characters

Comment: [50 bytes](https://tio.run/##XcvBioMwFEDR/XyFukrAKPMBCkVoK5TuyixKLSF9BtunLyRxpjM/7yRddOH2cu5dfkun7GC8mOgGS18trqpVVbvCgkGpgJXnToq/S1HqIX9W9fP8eSk8nYwB20gHjPNF0eQIoUDSrGfZHhDp@kMWbxln2TXjPEnKMnn1r5g/VscI@UQ5Dg@IQ/4a4jHCkQ6hrv0vzUKTF4OPXrx96DvyrV/7zdi1nUKQNvru7Tdj28S69prSfkZMlTQuHmk8gte0DbkJdfkH). Or 47 if you don't bother taking the second input, which is irrelevant.

Comment: @Shaggy Thanks! I've added it as a separate version, since the new rules are quite different from the original ones.

Comment: fail `!prob!!lem!s!Olved!!`

Comment: @l4m2, that's a new test case which changes the spec *yet again*. A `+` before the `.` in the RegEx will get around it.

Comment: @Shaggy By adding a `+`, we're not going to capitalize the right character anymore. ([This works](https://tio.run/##ZcxBS8MwGMbxu5@i6WUJpu1d6MYoqIWhgogHsSW2b0s16RuSbFa/fE12GLN7rn9@z6c4CNuYQbtkxBbmLp9tvrapAS1FAzR7q0Ty@35NU7bJ@oHTmk8sX0@bKXX4ojWYQlig7Ga1YnODo0UJqcSedjS@Bymx/kYj25hHcR0zFp2WZdGxv4Z8tZAK@IhcDl8QIP8Hg1TwgDtfl@4H90mPLhlccMmF8/0OXemWbquqsmokCBNcdeG2qixCXboeSbeXkjRC2yDJufSux1ufC1@XkmiDH4RIUMSSR3mAlpDTg5dPPu9APR/T/Ac) but is only 1 byte shorter than the original version.)

Comment: well i saw it's added after the comment

Comment: ```s=>c=>s.replace(u=/./g,x=>u=x==c?'':u?x:x.toUpperCase())```?

Comment: Your explanation says `u < 1?a:b` checks for empty string so why not just do `u?b:a`

Comment: @Downgoat D'oh. This may have been derived from an earlier version where it really was needed. Or (more probably), I'm just stupid. :) Thanks!

Comment: @l4m2 Indeed. (Sorry, I missed your comment.)

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>61</s> <s>53</s> 55 bytes

*-8 bytes thanks to Dennis!*

```c
f(s,c)char*s;{for(;*s;putchar(*s++))if(*s==c)*++s&=95;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYyxCoAgFAB/JRzKp72xIcS5j4gGeWA5lNGzIaJvN92O4zjClShnL7knoM1dis3r4yVNgfNOVUnFWgMEX8BaAqU1t3YczJd3Fw4Jb60anhcr8Ik3TjFhSMLUa4cdlPAH)

Comment: Suggest `*s==c?*++s&=95:0;` instead of `if(*s==c)*++s&=95;`

Answer (score 3):

## [sed 4.2.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) (-r), 21

```
s/[^a-z]+(.)?/\u\1/gi
```

I tried `\W` instead of `[^a-z]`, but unfortunately that doesn't match `_`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctLDsIgEADQPaegG6JxkHgC485u3VoxWEZCnHYaPmn08KJv/zL61rK5Wqc/t91mvz2aoQ4HE2JrZyTi@8qJvJgQZgaKLwQJ4s1VBy46FpBanCbb25HQJZBWBO6elagb3ZJBdmLFmLx61KLKpf63@vJSIs@56fQD)

Comment: By our new standards, [each invocation of a flags is considered a different language](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/59487), and thus your answer can be changed to `sed 4.2.2 (-r), 21 bytes`.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Sounds good - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 22 bytes

```apl
{⍵~⍨1(819⌶@(⍵=¯1⌽⊢))⍺}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc6xSsNAHMfxPU/RLPm3kKDZVChYC2pAHERwSzmTSzh68V@SC6VIXRTB2kgXH0Cnbk46CC4@yv9F4j8xNxzH5/sbTsy0Fy@ExtSLtCgKFdX08qqQHje7dcL3LVWfd1Rt/f6ev0/rr8M@w/D3w6f1D63eBwOqvpd1bbopPb3l/KTVfbLD5QBwCvT8AIlQGhh4ki8tOJVa42SOuY6hxwcmYP7xqjULMuneoKvVVLaDHri8yOQ5njVkwQJLL0XjKdN1jzvjCZrAcB9lYRBGWoq86yH3URaMW7IgRTsptbYjMSuaBdjcUzxmGzdkwVyqPHauS@OYi5J/AQ4vWjwqzWVDfw)

Comment: Why Dyalog Classic for this answer?

Comment: at the time, unicode dyalog answers were required to link to a single-byte encoding (or else scoring would default to utf8), so it was easier to post in classic dyalog

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg) `-p`, 19 bytes

```perl6
s:g[<:!L>(.)]=$0.uc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHBCsIwDADQe/6iIENhHZ48DBW8Key0qziZXSzFbCltw/Dnje9FTHRQza2/H1vTnbfN7nHa7Btxqlck4ufKiSaYsV64pvBB@LJYz8WGApd5uA2OcEzg2byFyLgxZlgxpKl6SalKL/jjWAIvWW38Aw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
Œt⁸1¦«⁸ḟ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYo7DoJAFAD7PcW@hgpi9gh2WhiNnQ2Ez4OsPlwCi0ipR/ACdlpoZSxI7DAeBC6ybjOTTGaLRK0xv4seT53ob/3DeuiuZvi8h@41np/f@8RyY8zMripoVEkJD1iO7l65JHfIXdaq2suU9qTmHpvm/tyPCcOS@yxTkNZEEIdFxYE1KMvEiWrt6HWN3GGrUkWEC5HKIyZir7hgUNgGQJhDBUs6YAIc/g)

#### How it works

```
Œt⁸1¦«⁸ḟ  Main link. Left argument: s (string). Right argument: c (character).

Œt        Title case; capitalize the first character of each word.
  ⁸1¦     Replace the first character of the result with the first character of s.
     «⁸   Take the character-wise minimum of the result and s.
          Note that uppercase letters have lower code points than lowercase ones.
       ḟ  Filterfalse; remove all occurrences of c.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>83</s>, <s>66</s>, 64 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to Luis Mendo. `upper` instead of `toupper`.

```matlab
@(s,c,k=upper(s(i=find(s==c)+1)))[strsplit({s(i)=k,s}{2},c){:}];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JczNisIwFEDhvW/RTZNgWqjLGQLOblwI4nawUtMbCb32lvyoQ@mzdzJk@x04pEP3hNWouq7XPfdSy0HFaQLHPbfK2LHnXiktto0Q4scH5ye0gc@pCjVIv8y7RWoxfyyXz9Vw9g2IdH2Rw55JdmVik/ABciSJdoBkMtsvxepOobIhSZXt69EeWo3QuWRttjsVJiIWupt80iLrC6zry1sMZTjH/2uZ/eTohnBsjH1D34yUSsPE@gc)

Wow, that's probably the messiest piece of Octave-code I've ever written! This uses two of the tricks posted in [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/163105/31516) tips question, namely Argument list, and cell arrays.

#### Explanation:

**Argument list input:**

```matlab
@(s,c,k        % An anonymous function that may take three input variables, s, c, k
               % where the third argument has the default value:
 k=upper(s(i=find(s==c)+1))
```

`k` is here the first character in `s` after each separator `c`, converted to upper case. The index of each capitalized character is stored in `i`.

**Cell array body:**

We create a cell array with two elements, one were we say that all i'th characters should be substituted by its counterpart in `k`, and the other one with `s`, that is now already updated. We index this using `{2}` so that we only get the whole, modified string back. This is fed to `strsplit`, which splits it into cells at the separator character. We convert it to a comma-separated list using `{:}`, and concatenates it back to a string using square brackets `[]`.

Apologies if that didn't make any sense to you... It barely makes sense to me :P

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 20 bytes

```
T`lLp`LL_`[\W\d_]+.?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcjBCoJAEADQ@/zFHJIgDfyC6FSBUkTQIdNVd5Sl0ZF1N@vrt97xWXJmrMNqfVDhpjibVJZV6lHcC109N9tdCEdilmoRyxoGikeJ2bwIvuKTXlxiHOyH8lS2TLWFXrDzzNjW0wwLGaujxrvIXT3BxUrDlKed@ZBORwGc/oPINOCMZ36TRvwB) Takes the string only, separator optional. All non-alphabetic characters are deleted but any following alphabetic character is uppercased. Previous 34-byte version accepted arbitrary input:

```
T`l`L`(?=.*(.)$)\1+.
(?=.*(.)$)\1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcjBCoJAEADQ@/zFQImWCvsBEZ0qKIroGLrqjrI0urLuZn391rHje5acHqqwjPcy3CXLk4y3m3wV58kieYh1Dv@EEA7EbMrZWFYl9JQOJmX9pBQ@xmedcZl2Gez64lg0TJUtoDPYemZsqnFCmElbFdXeRe7mKYKrNTXTWbT6TUoMRgCOv0Jk6nHCC79IIX4B) Link includes test suite. Assumes the input consists of the string and character concatenated together. Explanation: The first stage transliterates all characters immediately following occurrences of the end character from lower to upper case and the second stage then deletes all occurrences of the end character.

For both solutions, using a right-to-left match instead of a `+` also works.

Comment: Since the input is guaranteed to only contain alphabetic characters and the separator, you can use `[^a-z]` instead of the lookaheads [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JchBCsIwEADA@/5iD5aCjdAneFJBUcSbmKZt1hLcdkuaWPXzUfA2jKfghjot8o1JLr8YNntz1bX63JYr@ANS2hKzVLN4thX0VAxSsHtQAW@JqpOgXFCw7vVOt0y119AJ3iMztvU4IczkvM2aGLJwjpTByUvDdCjv7kW2HKQEHH@FyNTjhEd@kkX8Ag "Retina 0.8.2 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, 83 bytes

```scala
def f(s:String)={val w=s.split("[^a-zA-Z]");w(0)+w.tail.map(_.capitalize).mkString}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdBBT4MwFMDx@z7FKwcCWSHuqpkJNz0sGr1pZCnwWOoetKFlzC377Fj1MNbZU5N/fq/pM6UgMariE0sLKyFbwL3FtjKQaQ3H2VhhDXVkbl9tJ9tNvDzuBMGwNKnRJG0UvOciOWTJ20cQ3w3RTTwfUiskpY3Q0TothZZWkDxgnDbbvxmnEUC7i6U2Ch6QSK0H1VEFHNbwe5b3EMDcPTvNQRzPJrBB3ipOcovcQfDhJHvwS/XJRtlEWg7JNTxnz2VN/piXhKLjkF@7c/bcRrG6J2JuFYYD8900e3JA2VVh0dvQvvTum@GlvMyefe5UQbha1HKP1cKtYnFh/exppl1njLBhhj3RDivGJvq//DPhNH4D)

Explanation:

```scala
def f(s: String) = {                        // takes a String "s" as input
  val w = s.split("[^a-zA-Z]");             // split on non-alpha chars
  w(0) + w.tail.map(_.capitalize).mkString  // upper case first letter of all words except first one and join array into a String
}                                           //
```

Answer (score 2):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 6 <s>7</s> bytes

*1 byte saved by not using argument*

```
ÓÁˆ/õ±
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v///Dkw42HOvQPbz208f//3FSdvHydnMzs1P86AA)

The program takes in the text as input and the char as an argument.

Hexdump:

```
00000000: d3c1 882f f5b1                           .../..
```

This is a simple substitution. Uncompressed, it looks like the following

```
:s/\A(.)/\u\1/g
```

Perform a global substitution in which `\A`, a non-alphabetic character, followed by a character `(.)` is replaced with uppercased `\u` first capture group `\1`

Comment: Doesn't work for input where `c` is a special regex character

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Fixed, and thanks to this I found a shorter solution :D

Answer (score 2):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), <s>57</s> 54 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to [Cows quack](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41805/cows-quack)*

```
{(_/`\Q$_`)|{pull;[upperCase(_[:1]),_1[1:]]if[#_1>0]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LZBda4MwFIbv8ysSN4qCZfO2w0FX6Fbouk/YhVprNXZh0RM0rhs9/naX2J2L8D4PJ28gDRTZcCLUTElnIY2Hk5te7eKXy3Tn4Ul1Ut5EnVK8WWQtd9NoFiSenwZRMEsSUUYXaXB7nfT90BNSZaKm565WSaFpy1XoxDE6FGkJDc18uvdpTgsYl@yorv10rffsjmvPHOo80yaoRtTazerWpw4NqWOu2uSaYG2YewY9xzt31@1YWkDNST88cCkhPUIjC0xxpA8LpOJ@Db4UXxx9rPgG1iaSX@imB9BToXGKBu5BrzSZV9vVNpc8a3CL82q1sJEcgJXmW1ieqRYZHmBpaGGAHLloism@0xP92nGc4CjuOv1ukDw3sJf8MSjFDy@CGjDAf7W0ZgOEKcOMSV6xlj3Jb14w84BdWvPqbRR/)

Explanation:

```
{
  (_/`\Q$_`)| /* Pull two strings and split the first with the second */
  {
    pull;                /* Pull one string and print it */
                         /* For each string _1 in the stream: */
                         /*   If _1 is not empty: */
    [                    /*     Print: */
      upperCase(_[:1]),  /*       The first character capitalized */
      _1[1:]             /*       The rest of characters */
    ]if[#_1>0]           /*   End if */
  }
}
```

Comment: You can leave out the `\E` from the regex, and `_[0:1]` → `_[:1]`

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 87 bytes

```
func[s c][b: split s c prin b/1 foreach w next b[if w <>""[w/1: uppercase w/1 prin w]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc2xasMwEAbgPU9x8uDJJng1pdCtHUpLViEFSzqlImdLyFKdEPrsrtJC6@0/vrv7I5r1gIaLne1XmyfNZ9CCqx7mQC5BmSBEN4Had2B9xEF/wAITXhIo7mzJD49VxZd910MOAaMeZoQy/p4tQoj1nhJYuD0jkT8uPpL5gupY7f5kxGbyDbkzFmg2cPW5PfnUulSgreBfnkYpX6TUhEMsJuUWT57ZTMT0EOaCbPNxQRdNrXKq0yHf6@rt4Xv0ivC1s@6Cppt88W7rLJQFxghHNrM3@kTD2E/B@g0)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
¡ćsvyćusJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0MIj7cVllUfaS4u9/v9X4ypPzSxKUVNLKi1RKwkqTQUA)

**Explanation**

```
¡           # split the string on the char
 ć          # extract the head of the resulting list
  s         # swap the head to the bottom of the stack
   vy       # for each string y in the rest of the list
     ću     # extract the head and capitalize it
       s    # swap it below the rest of the string
        J   # join everything to one string
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>91</s> 83 bytes

```
$a=explode($argv[2],$argv[1]);echo array_shift($a);foreach($a as$i)echo ucfirst($i);
```

Run with `-r`. Was 2 bytes shorter using split instead of explode, but ^ test fails due to regex.

-8 thanks to [Med](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41036/med)

Comment: You can remove `{`and `}` from the for loop, it will only treat the next statement as body of the condition.

Comment: You can even do the echo inside the loop:
`$a=explode($argv[2],$argv[1]);echo array_shift($a);foreach($a as$i)echo ucfirst($i);`

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 64 bytes

Pure regular expression solution using https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacecase.html. Unfortunately separators can be underscores so I couldn't use `\w` to capture letters. Improved version taking advantage of gsub's ignore.case parameter to save on `[a-zA-Z]`. Correction thanks to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen, who has a 25% shorter solution in the comments.

```r
function(s,c)gsub('[^a-z]([a-z]?)([a-z]*)','\\U\\1\\E\\2',s,T,T)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jdBbS8MwGIDhe3/FUqEHSQr1XmUOp4U5RSteLHb0kJZi0m@0iVP/fE1q54WzsgYSCO/DF9p0xVlXqDqTFdRuizOvbFXqOqs4IZ8v7srsF973eeI52KH0idKA0itKTx3c4ghHXle41g3jHNZbaHhuYWtteceT3x8h5HzSd88mO9opf6f8A9UHKL8E6VdyDA1Mh9cgQ2mQYLgGzKtXhi2zxpVgS1jobhhF9CjSjyIHjpqKOIwzzpJGo/gfNBXhzGQGlYAKxTnKkk2rGRr9FyXMdTfTmWFbVjW5nSppywfFNLT3Yc/68FLJSGcG3jeQcnYbFNU7y4MaNA32aC@Hcm7CJRiLNvoKIc4EatEdf2M5@uPJP3jBxGNfdV8)

https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen 's solution, with an extra character removed (by using `?` for optional):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 47 bytes

```r
function(s,c)gsub("[^a-z]+(.)?","\\U\\1",s,T,T)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jdDdSsMwFMDxe59iiVBaTAp9AJU5mBbmFK14Ye3ox2kppj2jTZz68jUJnRfOypK75P/jhHRDeT6Uqs1lja3bs9yrepW59CVJ@dfrmet7l5TROH6K44CynkUs8obSpTcgBG522IlC32@odzr7vTjnFzPbPZvsZK/8vfKPVJ@o/AqlX8spNDIdXqMMpUENsBaZqN@AUbOnVQNrXOluHMX1KG5H8SNHzZskTHIBaadR8g@aN@HCZAZVSEolBMnTba8ZmfyLCpe6W@jMsB3UXeFkSjryQYGGziG0zIZXSkY6M/C@w0zAbVDWH1AELWoaHFArx3JpwjUaS7b6iBABDenJnXiHgvzx5B@8gubRVsM3)

Comment: Your TIO link shows that this doesn't work for the last test case...

Comment: ...but you can fix it for [48 bytes](https://tio.run/##jdDdSsMwFMDxe59iiTJaTAp9AIU5mBbmFK14Ye3oR1qKac9oE6fiu3cnofPCWVlyl/x/nJC2Ly76QjeZqqBxOpa5ZadTh77ECf96PXe87zOXMhpFT1HkU9axkIVuXzj0RkgJ6y20Msf7NXVPJ78X5/xyYrtnk53slbdX3pHqE7RXgvIqNYYGhuE1qEAZVAvWAJPVm2DU7HFVixUssRtGcRzF7Sh@5KhZHQdxJkXSIor/QbM6mJvMoBJIoaUkWbLpkJHRvyhhgd0cM8O2omrzaarVVD1ogXB6CC2z4ZVWIWYG3reQSnHrF9WHyP0GkPoH1MqhXJhwBcaSDR4RIkVNOnIn30VO/njyD16K@tFW/Q4)...

Comment: ...or (actually using the argument ```c```) for [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##jdLRSsMwFIDh6/kUSZTZYlrcAyiooA50ik68GZOsPe2KSc5I022C7z5PyhzonKy9KYf/yymlblWcrYrGZr5CG9Uyi8u6mUQzVXs4jcRoJGQmxUmUfh7FIpY0eBmNekLWciiH8aqIxC1ojW8LdDoXUryJ@JD9vpIkOWdt9xqyg2@Vfqt0T/WBTVqiTyu/C60ZhTfo@z4gA9Ki1NU7SBHu3crAAO@oW69KaFXSrkr2XHVhxv1xpkE5QuN/0IXpX4UsoBJ50WjNMzWrifGd36LEa@quKAtsAZXLu5PGd/1TAwS727BlbXjZ@CFlAT46nGi47xXVEvKeRaK9LdrKdXkdwgEGy2c04lyD4TV/0HPI@R@vvMF3YJ7bamPTNP3JabA@odPZOBpuKD2zCJbKzDSwReWnTFn0U3DMok3oD8pZNlVOZZ5Gfqr8cc3yqijAgfWscGhoCgwtsLKag2WqphOYcmVjqIhXXw)...

Comment: Would you like to add your (growing number of) R golfs to the [Language of the month](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19304/language-of-the-month-for-september-2020-r) page (edit the first 'answer' there...).  It's nice for other R-golfers (and would-be-R-golfers) to be able to easily find examples to learn from...

Comment: Thanks for the correction @DominicvanEssen, much better than mine! I'm amused that not using the argument is still better!

Comment: Me too, and based on the 'Scala' answer that the OP mentions, it seems that you don't even need to accept ```c``` as a function argument...

Comment: Well done on shaving another byte off my attempt!  By the way, if you're embedding links, you can make your text more readable by using a link-label in square-brackets [ ] immediately followed by the link itself in parentheses ( ).

Answer (score 1):

## LaTeX, 97 bytes

### The function

```latex
\def~#1#2{{\seq_set_split:Nnn~{#2}{#1}\seq_map_function:NN~"}}\def"{\let"\text_titlecase_first:n}
```

### Complete document with test cases

```latex
\documentclass[preview,border=3.14]{standalone}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\catcode`\~13
\catcode`\"13

\def~#1#2{{\seq_set_split:Nnn~{#2}{#1}\seq_map_function:NN~"}}\def"{\let"\text_titlecase_first:n}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
~{Hello_world}_

~{me,no,like},

~{you-got-it}-

~{Am^I^clear}^

~{go!full!caps}!

~{weird&but&tRue}&

~{ProbleM1fixed1no}1

~{!prob!!lem!s!Olved!!}!
\end{document}
```

### Results (in PDF)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [Pinecone](https://github.com/wmww/Pinecone), 314 bytes

```
s:String.input;p:String.input;k:IntArray:s.len;k.set:0,-1;o:"";n:1;i:0|i<s.len|i:i+1@((s.sub:i,i+1)=p?(k.set:n,i;n:n+1))k.set:n,s.len;i:1|i<n+1|i:i+1@(x:k.get:i-1;y:k.get:i;x:x+1;j:s.sub:x,y;e:1|e<256|e:e+1@((j.sub:0,1)=e.ascii?(e<96?(o:o+(e.ascii)+(j.sub:1,(j.len)))|(o:o+(e-32).ascii+(j.sub:1,(j.len))))))print:o
```

This was extremely fun....

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
/ḣǐJṅ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%2F%E1%B8%A3%C7%90J%E1%B9%85&inputs=.%0Ahello.world&header=&footer=)

Comment: [Use the `s` flag for 4 bytes](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=%2F%E1%B8%A3%C7%90J&inputs=!%0Ago!full!caps&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 87 bytes

```r
g<-function(s,x,z=strsplit(s,x,T)[[1]])cat(z[1],capwords(z[-1]),sep="")
example(chartr)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZFRb9owEIDf8yscV0Kx5ETKXlsm0Qo2JEqnwbSHCqqQXEI0J7ZiZ9Aifjs7uxRBKVPtSLGt77s7n5vd1XRZaoKfWQLJ2zo1paxxkxgC66RSAoJ0mTSmYSSDvKxBk6CWhiA0HT4wz0sTtZJNpslNePADzYk2TZka0iWD3mjSZ2TjERxIn4KMqEQbCIxslYIm0O3CmnVhY8T4McadeTo2Lt8J/IVdkzIPXvMyYqSQKxuQERAaiN5@FOdoaFBYLaWcpFKIRKGDW5zMeTpRSjzb8FqJ0rgr2sUrxLi9Gie/Jv1o3LvvT/DYL3VUt0IEdVKBxkIY87a74iY8atOav3SPQq75lD0@xrMZSxMTvOCKv/UXd2E8YxzL7FLKvHevs8tP@hpFEdsU7ndtQ1GPsq2XB/Q7CCGfMKLIKKdPlF2dNSIMw6/Ecb8tdrCiNyv6pPUs26iQJirNJWmvIfhNmqGxUgW8llyUf4BTOy9bFYzlCLl9qhBThS5V@MlUvWo@nKcCkgal@X@kXjW8s5iVCunn@Kg@votGzb/Yi0IOkLtDzGorKJuss2hNx/xsAcXOueg0B962ZoqYFX80ciHgPs7LNWRxLVGNz1Rn7smBBcfSur7CI98XUPnafxB/IfM/KPkgj6CaOGr3Dw)

Uses [this trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144559/80010) can can not be properly executed in TIO so I simulated it.

We need the `T` otherwise one of the test cases fails.

Answer (score 0):

### Groovy, 43 bytes, <strike>45 bytes</strike>

```
s.replaceAll(/\$c(.)/){it[1].toUpperCase()}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##TZDRasIwFIbv@xRRRFtoK7sdOHCFbcLYxdjYRa2SpWkXlnhKkk6k9Nm7k1jR3JyQ7/t/yKk1wN9pGEpekYoyYcmK5AEhubknixcuJeyPoGW5iAkeho97vOoL/PKsiC8JxeMDxFL88nPAJ@IxofgbvDp09U/QJjXYRNgbPxl9hM9gN/bGX6vdZsckp/rG343@Wm0yj65@DZOqlXLCaGN8wvmT0a/hCVnm0DVx5EKX8@/Wzu17637hEvMx4eFjaz8cKoogcGsrQdjQoBiRDltMqnkjKeNrKcPldsbCNFpGnbD5XZFa@GwarjNqeBj1QR8Efukpp@yHdESR5AErqDFc23OxSrFapVi@WuHUiBstDlYeyDSfdYj7mLjJ@gLT/qr7KVYPwz8). Test suite included excluding the last item as it lacks the separator char `c`.

Answer (score 0):

## Go, <s>138</s> <s>92</s> 87 bytes

Dropped 46 bytes thanks to [@Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis)' title case idea.

```
func f(s,d string){p:=Split(s,d);Print(p[0]+Replace(Title(Join(p[1:]," "))," ","",-1))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdBNa8MwDAbgc/wrbB2CzZyxXFt22G0bjJVut64paaIEU3@ROOtG6W/P4vQ2chGSeITgbd3oy@pUtkhNqSwhynjXBcpJck@hMQHmpg@dsm0PRBDSDLaaMRf0QpKGwzNq7Q5n1@kaJIUDCJJspoPA4cvGYTIGpXVSqxNGIpfIrxuy1oVMhUiyJfJkipei0lh2kRRL5Iyqq9PjENKwHeZn6RLbdO6o8S1v1A/WuXUR5kuQ@UkyptGwnr3rb6wZi5j9x9dxTqbhvazpLTBx8avHD69ViEuxvnG/e9jfbdHrskL@qYJG/uqmOP0uX@0lUBAiVgkgs1yI6zj@AQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 10 bytes

```
ΣΓ·:mΓo:ax
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9zic5MPbbfKPTc53yqx4v///4r/FQuK8pMUFXNScxWLFf1zylJTFBUB)

#### Explanation

```
ΣΓ·:mΓ(:a)x  -- example inputs: 'x' "abxbcxcdxdex"
          x  -- split on character: ["ab","bc","cd","de"]
 Γ           -- pattern match (x = head) (xs = tail) and do..
  ·:         -- | construct list (x:xs) but with the second argument do..
    m        -- | | map (eg. "bc")
     Γ(  )   -- | | | pattern match on first character
      ( a)   -- | | | | upper-case it
      (: )   -- | | | | and join again
             -- | | | : "Bc"
             -- | | : ["Bc","Cd","De"]
             -- : ["ab","Bc","Cd","De"]
Σ            -- concatenate: "abBcCdDe"
```

Answer (score 0):

## [F# (Mono)](http://www.mono-project.com/), 122 bytes

```fs
let f(s:string)c=s|>Seq.mapi(fun i x->if i>0&&s.[i-1]=c then Char.ToUpper(x)else x)|>Seq.where((<>)c)|>Seq.toArray|>String
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc9RT8IwFAXgd39Fu8SxJQzk1cgSJEFJEI1gfDBCxrgbje3ubDuBxP8@7yYPwNjDku2c7zRNTKAwwxJzyNhsbyyoUoJliWdujdUiS/24b37DGXx3VJQLLykyJtguCEXCRHjjuqbzIYLeZz9mdkMbw02kO3N8y3PQ3s4HaYDt/P@B7QY0eN5d6MeHPxYHWkd7@qjPKnN62yRjzvXAYV7CnEeQEpdb1HLtsNay5bOTp9tldeO9Klw1tIJ2hm0pvoBw@xxXWsEUJ5Q37R6LIEUbCEs2uGSp8YB2bJt2oBbjRSwh0mQXl@xAjYdV3rQp8qSQksdRbkjzM002xREVhpQ39RaEXrurwrr2tahu7Z540nXjvrBzypv@ReNKwlMvETtY9zKkhd7RAvlDY1QVpthc4DkVOJeguOHP8gfWnB/d47AwATWrw7L8Aw)

Answer (score 0):

## Java 10, 141 bytes

```java
s->c->{var r=s.split("\\"+c);var r=a[0],t;for(int i=0;++i<a.length;r+=t.isEmpty()?"":(char)(t.charAt(0)&~32)+t.substring(1))t=a[i];return r;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jZBRSyMxEIDf/RXJPtSE3Q3t@XZrKyKKPsgd@qitpNm0ps4mSzKpV6T@9RqvhT040IVAwsx8M/lmJdeyXNUvOwUyBHIrjX07IiSgRKPIKmVFRANiEa1C46y4OjxO79Ebuyy@rLl4ll4q1L4g@/LJhCgy3oVyosrJ21p64sdBhBYMsuzxMcsVr/ZR@TCcFlgtnGfGIjHjYZXn5lQK0HaJz5XPxyhMuGxa3DB@lmU/mUrTOEPxeZ8jG/LB@8kPnqMIcR7@jmcjzjG1NtPKa4zeEl9td1USTqeNc0jOB/W1MzVp0jrY/ucPUyL552oIud8E1I1wEUWbUgiWKSHbFjYsu9YA7unVeagzfggePx1zXn2LNrqwrgDzojuy6EVuXCyXDkuDHVn2Is@b2c1MgZa@I2e9yKWjiwhAlWxDx9Je7Ks2vh7MIw7wLv5jO@hF//ZuDvp2tDB/dD2yruNHvXjapgaUgm5ooL9grWtK/zfYHm13Hw)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->c->{                    // Method with String and character parameters and String return-type
  var r=s.split("\\"+c);   //  Split String by character (with potential regex char)
  var r=a[0],              //  Result-String, starting at the first item
      t;                   //  Temp-String to reduce bytes
  for(int i=0;++i<a.length;//  Loop in the range [1, length_of_array)
      r+=                  //    After every iteration: append the result-String with:
         t.isEmpty()?      //     If the current item empty:
          ""               //      Append nothing
         :                 //     Else:
          (char)(t.charAt(0)&~32)
                           //      Capitalize the first character
          +t.substring(1)) //     And append the other characters as is
    t=a[i];                //   Set `t` to the current String-item of the array
  return r;}               //  Return the result-String
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
óKo{cplòüö\
```

[Run and debug it](http://stax.tomtheisen.com/#p=a24b6f7b63706c9581945c&i=_%0AHello_world%0A%0A,%0Ame,no,like%0A%0A-%0Ayou-got-it%0A%0A%5E%0AAm%5EI%5EClear%0A%0A%21%0Ago%21full%21caps%0A%0A%26%0Aweird%26but%26tRue%0A%0A1%0AProbleM1fixed1no%0A%0A%21%0A%21prob%21%21lem%21s%21Olved%21%21&m=1)

**Explanation**

```
/BsF1:/s^s|dl                 # Full Program, unpacked, Implicit Input
/                             # Split on substrings (Split input with symbol to split on)
 B                            # Remove first element from array. Push the tail of the array, then the removed element.
  s                           # Swap first two elements of stack
   F                          # Start for loop
    1:/                       # Split array at index; push both parts.
       s^s                    # Swap first two elements of stack, capitalize character, swap first two elements 
         |dl                  # Get length of stack, listify that amount (entire stack), implicit output of array
```

There's a few parts I would really like to fix somehow. I can get it down to about 8 bytes, but it fails on the last test case >.<

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-pl`, 36 bytes

```ruby
$_.gsub!(/[^a-z]+(.|$)/i){$1.upcase}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchLDoIwEADQfW8xCSEQ@YQjuNOF0bg1QgoMpHFgmn5E/Fzd6ls@49s1hKgpRutbSMpLLfPndZMU7ygtVfqKqsLrTlr8hLBDIm4WNtSLCbOZM1I3FCv7fGSXKye2U72vO0JpxMgweCLopLZiQWX6uPUudmeP4mS4JTxUg3pgX80sQP8HgHACC0e6Yw/wZe0Uzzbkmn4)

Takes only the string without second argument. Uses the block version of `gsub!` method because with common `gsub! x,y` syntax `$1` is not readily filled with match data. `|$` in regex is necessary for the test case with separator in the end.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 77 bytes

```python
o=[]
for x in s.split(c): o.append(chr(ord(x[0])-32)+x[1:])
print(''.join(o))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCsMgEADAu68QL9mlRtrmFvAl4iGoRYu4okLs6@1M/Y1I5VhdixhyJnlTy16O0IdgTgspFmlj2YcanzwV3lWvOQ1weHJSV62heHCxATUP0zwt7scbH9O8ToustlQGbJv6UipAiGv9AQ)

This assumes that the string is ASCII encoded and assumes that `s` and `c` are preloaded variables containing the input.

```python
for x in s.split(x)       #loop through items in the string s split by x
    o.append(             #add the following to c
        chr(              #turn the following number into a character
            ord(          #turn the following character into a number
                x[0]      #the first character in string x
            )-32          #subtract 32 from this number
        +x[1:]            #add everything past and including the second character in string x
```

This solution works on the fact that in ASCII encoding, [lowercase letters are positioned 32 entries after capitalised letters](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Edit: i just realised that this also capitalises the first character in the string, which it shouldn't. but i'm quite proud of my nonsense, so i'll leave this up if that's allowed

Comment: What is `s` supposed to be ?

Comment: @MuhammadSalman `A string s and a character c. `

Comment: Lovely, make it work, Go here and see if it works or not : [TIO](https://tio.run/#python3). When it does tell me ?

Comment: oops! i just realised i made a mistake when changing the variable names, c=[] is supposed to be any other variable

Comment: @MuhammadSalman [here](https://tio.run/##BcFBCsMgEADAu68QL9mlRtrmFvAl4iGoRYu4okLs6@1M/Y1I5VhdixhyJnlTy16O0IdgTgspFmlj2YcanzwV3lWvOQ1weHJSV62heHCxATUP0zwt7scbH9O8ToustlQGbJv6UipAiGv9AQ "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Edited to add the specification, and a TIO link

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 23 bytes

```
Ya^by@0AL(UC@_.@>_M@>y)
```

might be shorter with regex substitution.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/MjEuqdLBwNFHI9TZIV7PwS7e18GuUvP///@5qTp5@To5mdmp/3UA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), <s>130</s> 125 bytes

```
|s,c|(|mut u|s.chars().flat_map(|x|if x==c{u=1;vec![]}else if u>0{u=0;x.to_uppercase().collect()}else{vec![x]}).collect())(0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc@9boMwFAXgnaewMxBbgiisTROpS9QOVat2rBrkmEuCesHIPwkV8OzUztIOZbPP/a58rJ2xU9mQWlQN46SPCLFgLJsGk8iBDbWzxA1mJc9CG8ZXJQqb16JlQzdUJem2W9m7bba5gKQfnyOgAeJzt1v7eL3pVlblrm1BS2HA70uFCNIyfqP9ba37HP8MOFvziRC@icYo8s1Cnfv9jpV3ZM@j6xk0@JJ7f2tYbKxOSOjGSboj71ZXzSkKn2j9yWJD2aIfFwkp2eIREFV@VRoLHyzzJfdP/AdrSBqVYPUFwSWz7lu59KRsWtng0ln3UB@eDhJB6OAOs@6kaOkQqRStCZLOyitUuoiPzsb2zd1axrP2VasjwnNWVh0UWaOCzmY1bT2nFKGmhr7gBQpKf7uM0w8)

-5 bytes thanks to Aiden4

So Rust has no built-in support for regular expressions or title case, and [the uppercase function can return multiple characters](https://tio.run/##KyotLvn/Py1PITcxM09DU6GaS0EhJ7VEISe/PLUoObE4VcFWQf3wfHVrqHhpQQFE3EohuKQoMy8dKA9Xq1eSHw9XoKGpl5yfk5OaXKKhCdJdAFRdkpOnqKFUXaukgzAIKFn7/z8A)... On the plus side, this works for non-ASCII encodings :)

Comment: You can shave off 5 bytes if you use `flat_map()` instead of `map().flatten()`

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 45 bytes

```
""<>MapAt[Capitalize,##~StringSplit~All,2;;]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcxBa4MwGIDhe/9FIuQUGe7arSiD0R7KytxNtKT66UK/mJB@rttK/esuI9fnhdco@gSjSLdq6Z8Xzp82e@UKql6U06RQ/4JMkrkkr8ehdKhpLhDl43pdi@UQkKoPG2uVyN3oJnq13tTiIU/STZ/nSS3mslXjfFvd@BYQ7fFqPXZc8iO/y4AG5Ggl6jMEk9F@7JQOllJNQdJohWl2TYugfLAm2mBZPyGyVrlLUBb1Ctp34jSRoPfp/yqiH7w9IeyzXn9Dl402lCwW5kJiDMGwC3vDL@gYi7/VffkD)