# Find the Fibonacci Patterns

Tags: code-golf, fibonacci

You are probably familiar with the [Fibonacci sequence](http://oeis.org/A000045) where the first two terms are `0, 1` (or sometimes `1, 1`) and every term after that is the sum of the previous two. It starts like this:

`0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...`

Sometimes, the sequence contains numbers that have a particular pattern that I find interesting: the difference between any pair of adjacent digits is the same as any other pair. For instance, in the sequence starting with `0, 1`, the 18th term is `987`. `9-8=1` and `8-7=1`. I am mildly satisfied.

**Challenge**

Given two initial values `F(0)` and `F(1)`, output every number in the sequence generated by `F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)` that meets the following criteria:

- The difference between any pair of adjacent digits is the same as any other pair
- It is as least three digits long (1 and 2 digit numbers are not interesting for this pattern)

**Input**

- Two non-negative integers less than 10**10 (10 billion)

**Output**

- All integers that are less than 10**10 and meet the criteria in the Challenge section
- It is acceptable to output digits greater than 10**10 but it is not a requirement
- Given that repeated digits meet the pattern (e.g. `777`), it is possible that there are infinite numbers that meet the criteria but your program is not required to output forever
- If no such integers exist, output whatever you want so long as it's not a number (nothing, null, empty array, error message, sad face, etc.)
- If a number matching the pattern appears more than once in the sequence, you can output it once or as many times as it occurs
- If any input meets the criteria, it should be included in the output

**Rules**

- Input and Output can be in any [standard format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/38183)
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/38183) are forbidden
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes wins

**Examples / Test Cases**

```
Input , Output   
[1,10] , []   

[0,1] , [987]   
[2,1] , [123]   
[2,3] , [987]   

[61,86] , [147]   
[75,90] , [420]   
[34,74] , [1234]   
[59,81] , [2468]   
[84,85] , [7531]   

[19,46] , [111]   
[60,81] , [222]   
[41,42] , [333]   
[13,81] , [444]   
[31,50] , [555]   
[15,42] , [666]   
[94,99] , [777]   
[72,66] , [888]  
[3189,826] , [888888888]    

[15,3] , [159,258]   
[22,51] , [321,1357]   
[74,85] , [159,4444]   
[27,31] , [147,11111]   

[123,0] , [123,123,123,246,369]   
[111,0] , [111,111,111,222,333,555,888]
[111,222] , [111,222,333,555,888]      

[33345,692] , [987654321]   
[3894621507,5981921703] , [9876543210]
[765432099,111111111] , [111111111,876543210,987654321]   

[1976,123] , [123, 2222, 4321, 6543, 45678]
```

Comment: Suggested test cases: `[1976, 123] -> [123, 2222, 4321, 6543, 45678]`, `[3189, 826] -> [888888888]`, `[33345, 692] -> [987654321]`

Comment: @Arnauld Great find! I wonder which starting pair has the most output values less than 10B. Anything above that will be repdigits and that's boring.

Comment: @Arnauld Thanks for the test case corrections. In my original generator, I didn't include the inputs. I clearly missed those two when I went back and added them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 14 bytes

*Thanks to Emigna for pointing out a mistake, now corrected*

```
`yVdd~?yD]wy+T
```

Infinite loop that outputs the numbers as they are found.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P6EyLCWlzr7SJba8Ujvk/38jcy5jQwA) Note that in the online interpreter the results are displayed after the 1-minute time-out.

#### Explanation

Let `F(n)` and `F(n+1)` denote two generic consecutive terms of the Fibonacci sequence. Each iteration of the loop starts with the stack containing `F(n)`, `F(n+1)` for some `n`.

```
`         % Do...while
  y       %   Duplicate from below. Takes the two inputs F(0), F(1) (implicitly)
          %   in the first iteration
          %   STACK: F(n), F(n+1), F(n)
  V       %   Convert to string. Let the digits of F(n) be '3579' for example
          %   STACK: F(n), F(n+1), '3579'
  d       %   Consecutive differences (of ASCII codes)
          %   STACK: F(n), F(n+1), [2 2 2]
  d       %   Consecutive differences
          %   STACK: F(n), F(n+1),  [0 0]
  ~       %   Logical negate, element-wise
          %   STACK: F(n), F(n+1), [1 1]
  ?       %   If top of the stack is non-empty and only contains non-zero entries
          %   (this is the case for digits '3579', but not for '3578' or '33')
          %   STACK: F(n), F(n+1)
    y     %     Duplicate from below
          %     STACK: F(n), F(n+1), F(n)
    D     %     Display immediately. This prints the copy of F(n)
          %     STACK: F(n), F(n+1)
  ]       %   End
  w       %   Swap
          %   STACK: F(n+1), F(n)
  y       %   Duplicate from below
          %   STACK: F(n+1), F(n), F(n+1)
  +       %   Add. Note that F(n)+F(n+1) is F(n+2) 
          %   STACK: F(n+1), F(n+2)
  T       %   Push true. This will be used as loop condition
          %   STACK: F(n+1), F(n+2), true
          % End (implicit). The top of the stack is consumed as loop condition.
          % Since it is true, a new iteration will begin, with the stack
          % containing F(n+1), F(n+2)
```

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>17</s> <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
тFÂ2£O¸«}ʒS¥¥_W
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f8wNWFiMWX//9GCRsOCMsKjT8K4wqt9ypJTwqXCpV9X//9bMTExLDIyMl0)

**Explanation**

```
                  # implicitly input list of F(0) and F(1)
тF      }         # 100 times do:
  Â               # bifurcate current list
   2£             # take the first 2 items
     O            # sum
      ¸«          # append to list
         ʒ        # filter, keep only elements that are true after:
          S¥¥     # delta's of delta's of digits
             _    # logically negate each
              W   # min
```

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>85</s> <s>84</s> 81 bytes

```javascript
f=(p,q,a=[])=>p|q?f(q,p+q,![...p+''].some(x=d=n=>r=d-(d=x-(x=n)))/r?[...a,p]:a):a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZTLbsIwEEX3/Yp0RSKcYI8fsZEMH4JYRASqVjQvqopF/z0dE1BVJ05VL7xwzlyPr6/zVnwWl0P32nykVV0e@/5k44a0pLC7fWI3zVe7PcUtaZYted5lWdYsF4t9dqnfj/HVlraym86WaVzaa4oLVZIkq27rwII0@3WRrIv@UFeX@nzMzvVLfIoZiRhNkmg8VqsoffoNU4QnWQcbnXs4zOEM@Bjn/1BX2LpWUwVOXfh4LklkaAAXQD2cCxLlIqQOXHi8NNgNC/AglPZ4jfpaBvhccubxDPVF8LTMxxWdawfAwwV6KSCAc@7fFOMz6kL43nBUlyHrpZS@upxpRinl4QadNCbkZD7KAcZMhYzUWk80w0Pvg7lbB@nXAG4hQ/ZwcE@Oy1Ffc4G4bSTGzkKO3bHwGyAuGqNwYHxJRMPZJsOEqUV1Zfxqxmaq3cfbBM4FjA5xN0ymnL1TY6WHzp8SXBuhgEmKB5VGMwMsp7fbGv4YSgq023/awzI15u6OG0MTw8bDwP0e9eRHq/8G)

#### Testing adjacent digits

```javascript
![...p + ''].some(x = d = n => r = d - (d = x - (x = n))) / r
```

Both **x** and **d** are initialized to an anonymous function, which forces `NaN` for all arithmetic operations they're involved in. The first iteration of `some()` always gives `(d = [function] - n) === NaN` and `(r = [function] - d) === NaN` (falsy). On the second iteration, we have `d = x - n` (an integer) and `(r = NaN - d) === NaN` (falsy again). Starting from the third iteration, **r** is set to an integer which is non-zero if the difference between digit #3 and digit #2 is not equal to the difference between digit #2 and digit #1.

The number **p** is meeting the required criteria if and only if `some()` is falsy (all adjacent digits have the same difference) and the final value of **r** is **0** (there were at least 3 iterations). This gives `!false / 0 === true / 0 === Infinity` (truthy).

We may otherwise have:

- `!true / r` with **r > 0** or **r < 0**, which gives `false / r === 0` (falsy)
- `!false / NaN`, which gives `true / NaN === NaN` (falsy)

#### Halting condition

The recursion stops when `p | q` evaluates to **0**. This is guaranteed to happen when both **p** and **q** reach values around **10<sup>25</sup>** which are 84-bit long. Because JS has 52 bits of mantissa, the last 32 bits are zeroed. So, the 32-bit bitwise OR evaluates to **0**.

Due to the fast growing rate of the sequence, this happens rather quickly.

Answer (score 4):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>91</s> <s>90</s> 83 bytes

Saved 7 bytes thanks to Luis Mendo!

```matlab
@(t)eval"for i=3:99,if~diff(diff(+num2str(t(1))))disp(t(1))end,t=[t(2) sum(t)];end"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVLbasMwDH3vV5i9LGFaseRL7JWM/UfIQ2kbCKzraLPtoXS/3qmRbegECc7RkaxzosNmWn/vrkO7XC6vb9VU777X7w/D4ajG1rzECOPwux2HoZpfTx9fezpNx2qqsObYjqdPOe8@tjC13VRRrU5fe27Urxh7uG7ac4eAulegul4pteg04PwVQyMAJQDJZMDcMzxC8MKxCWocROlqSQtkLDQ2d7KCuQhBupP1QbBgIbgZa5xBwTCCTTdggrwupUQCWQRLM2RMmhVNZlmb7jQITkZzziWWy4Xee4GihRhliiZrIvAyRAihFIoXyErIJZQInFxqiN01Ljcoym50WyaiBgxm/wCxaGSjQGfL4PawTWB8TGnEnObT7WErgLUDK4PbkMKZDUqs/ww1B7sSovWETjfgYsBI2Ojym72zrERzOzlqXj3MkVtLQGFDKewvq8ViMa@tahW@HA8/p2pTg5o3tGOqyqu7OY@AF049qufnV/V4n6FL3XNuKDRe4usf)

Well, it works!

[`eval` with for loop inside](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/163131/31516) to save a few bytes. [Skipping colons and semicolons](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/107780/31516) to save a few. Uses the fact that a vector is considered truthy iff all elements are non-zero to save `any` or `all`.

Other than that, it's pretty much a straight forward implementation of Fibonacci.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>20 19</s> 18 bytes

```
>ȷ2ȧDIEƊ
+ƝḢ;Ɗȷ¡ÇƇ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/uxHajE8tdPF2PdXFpH5v7cMci62NdJ7YfWni4/Vj7/9DD7aH//5ubmZoYGxlYWuooGMIAAA)

`+ƝḢ;Ɗȷ¡` produces the first thousand (`ȷ`) terms in the series which will always be sufficient. I think there is probably a shorter way to do this. `+ȷ¡` gets close but only works if the first term is zero.

I am assuming we can take in the two numbers in reverse which allows one byte to `DIE`.

If we aren't required to output either of the inputs:

#### [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
>ȷ2ȧDIEƊ
+ṄÇ¡ß@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9qZWxsef//Psi3MsinRElFxooKK@G5hMOHwqHDn0D///8xOTc2/zEyMw)

Comment: Our thoughts to all fearless bytes that `DIEƊ` during the golfing process.

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8, <s>151</s> <s>144</s> <s>140</s> <s>136</s> 130 bytes

```java
(a,b)->{for(long n,m,d,p;;System.out.print(m>99&p==d?m+" ":""),m=a+b,a=b,b=m)for(m=n=a,d=p=10;n>9&d==p|p>9;d=n%10-(n/=10)%10)p=d;}
```

Infinite loop outputting the numbers when it finds them.
[Try it online](https://tio.run/##TU/BboMwDL3vKyykVYkaGPRGI7Mf2HrpseLgEFrRkRBB2mnq@PYsLT1MsmU/PdnvvTNdKR1ca8/6KzQ9TRN8UmdvLwCd9e14pKaF3R0CXIdOQ8P6wZ6AxGMoLiM1x441efJdAzuwgBAYCcXT6nYcxuXECiO0cFLufybfmmy4@MyNUYWZqixXDlG/m3UCyTZJuDBIayUIlVBo@P2JQYskNDoscmmrcqUR3a@rSqnRvhZ5yuxbpHhcuUMt5yAXX@6i@ujrae@RwsSMbO@j@ulQA/EloM0aZttv@Ih2GR3ymgv4h4uaP@POIRRFETabzR8) (times out after 60 sec).

**136 bytes** version with added 10<sup>10</sup> limit (`a<1e10`):

```java
(a,b)->{for(long n,m,d,p;a<1e10;System.out.print(m>99&p==d?m+" ":""),m=a+b,a=b,b=m)for(m=n=a,d=p=10;n>9&d==p|p>9;d=n%10-(n/=10)%10)p=d;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##bVLLTsMwELzzFVYlqkTdlqwfSUxw@QHgwhFxcB5FhcaxmhQJQb@9mAREHIgc2bPemZ2V91m/6mVjK/NcvpyKnW5bcqu35v2MkK3pqv1GFxW5@4KEvDbbkhTBrjFPREO/5WHmro7ud6vtdLctyB0xRJFToCEPl@v3TbMfKAZqKMFm@gorjLL7t7ar6lVz6FZ272oF9VrKuVWqvK4XMzK7nM1CqJVe5KBVDrmqwy@pWhmloVRWOQ2zlvNSKfth1zIrlTnHaBmYC3cVumNoVZkdT9ngzh7ynXP3bbLvpXadBvedq/708Eh0OLTZVW0XIDh@9osjwDGkU8jGMEZI43EgESA9OcYh4eOAkJB6kimHVIwDKIF7onE0oXAETj0Km2QwBOH5QDGhSA5SetYpxPGE4jVLKQivSDJ1ThNgXgZSBr4NxL8BSj1nLJU8piii5AaETFFSTCJ241WOBWc0khLw5/tnPvun7/P9SR5e36yKfnIH2emQ7kzwrXg8fQI)

**Explanation:**

```java
(a,b)->{         // Method with two long parameters and no return-type
  for(long n,m,  //  Temp numbers
           d,p;  //  Current and previous differences
      a<1e10;    //  Loop as long as `a` is still below 10^10
      ;          //    After every iteration:
       System.out.print(
                 //     Print:
        m>99     //      If the number has at least three digits,
        &p==d?   //      and the previous and current differences are still the same
         m+" "   //       Print the current number with a space delimiter
        :        //      Else:
         ""),    //       Print nothing
                 //     Go to the next Fibonacci iteration by:
       m=a+b,    //      Setting the temp-number `m` to `a+b`
       a=b,      //      Replacing `a` with `b`
       b=m)      //      And then setting `b` to the temp number `m`
    for(m=n=a,   //   Set both `m` and `n` to `a`
        d=p=10;  //   Set both `d` and `p` to 10
        n>9      //   Inner loop as long as `n` has at least two digits,
        &d==p    //   and `p` and `d` are still the same,
         |p>9    //   or `p` is still 10
        ;        //     After every iteration:
         d=n%10-(n/=10)%10)
                 //      Set `d` to the difference between the last two digits of `n`
                 //      And integer-divide `n` by 10 at the same time
      p=d;}      //    Set the previous difference `p` to `d`
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>102</s> 98 bytes

```python
f=lambda x,y:x<1e10and[x]*(len(set(int(a)-int(b)for a,b in zip(`x`,`x`[1:])))<2<99<x)+f(y,x+y)or[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVLLboMwEDy3X@EjJK7k9Qs7ol9iWQpRgoqUAkqpBP15un5A1EMjxayHmfXs4HGZPoaer2v7fm8@L9eGzHQ5zTXcgDX91c3@UNxvffF1m4qun4qmfAuPS9kOD9LQC@l68tONxXk@U/w7OPmyLGteW1vP5bEtFjofl3J4OL8GSdePdPiexqBzzgElwDwlzofFMdyGwpoqATwDwMUOiD8MjS2MjhyZoUpRYmNXyVmChKSkkrmTTJiyqIzdudQmYQZ5RoWyUgISBsiT6QTIkGa7lPMESfQheSiFyF5BbCwp85kCWSpaU0plltqEWusEWXRhbXRRbTPh4DqaMMY8hTELCJNwlWGOTBVPFTzEK9TWYp8tCuRuilfYCHKEqIB9TgyLEpZjwzdhwbCQrm1mAGyMUMWFBwuYAvpQ6PFpOL/c2f8RhbFSc1AM3ShrwHKo2PbZtZI4WP6uaceszbaj9dQ@/bDrpsBMt9p7f3p9GR94leONJOFKUtIWB9yV6y8)

Thx for 4 bytes from [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 55 bytes

```
q~{1$_99>"_`2\ew{{-}*}%""3,"?~_(+="0$p"*~;_@+_11_#<}g;;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v7Cu2lAl3tLSTik@wSgmtby6WrdWq1ZVSclYR8m@Ll5D21bJQKVASavOOt5BO97QMF7Zpjbd2vr/f0MjYwUDAA)

My first CJam submission, not very short but a lot of fun. Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: That's good to know, thanks for the tip! I've updated the submission.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 105 bytes

```hs
u%v|let s=u:scanl(+)v s=[n|n<-s,d<-[f(-).map fromEnum.show$n],length d>1,and$f(==)d]
f g=zipWith g=<<tail
```

Defines the operator `(%)` which returns an infinite list with all the solutions. To actually see the result on *stdout* we need to disable buffering (or run it in `ghci` or with `runhaskell`), [try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU67TsMwFN37FXcoki2SCAaEiOIOVB1YYOjAEDJY@BEL@zqyr1OB@u/BLEznKZ0zy/ylvd9cWGIiOH9n0qF7edvKzXr1miCL0udPiZ7d8rWqEa84tLlRQzsa1vIuyAVMiuGEJXR5jpc9To3XaGkGdbhvJKq9YUJwNe0MWPHjlndXMyuGgaTzW5AOQYCKO4D5rOm5GKOTQwuZVCwEr/HfqpWlIkEH7IOVfu3HibcHqG959f6@JC1VpZeYVIa6AVbTMSJppLw9PsDT3S8)

#### Explanation/Ungolfed

The function `f` is just a helper function that expects a binary function and a list, it applies the function `g` to all adjacent pairs. It's essentially the same as:

```hs
adjacent g xs = zipWith (tail xs) xs
```

The operator `(%)` is just a list comprehension that does some filtering (making sure that there are at least 3 digits & that the adjacent digits have the same distance):

```hs
u % v
  -- recursively define s as the "Fibonacci sequence" with f(0) = u and f(1) = v
  | let sequence = u : scanl (+) v sequence
  -- take all numbers from that sequence using the filters below
  = [ number | number <- sequence
  -- convert to string, get the ASCII codepoints and build a list of the adjacent differences
        , let differences = adjacent (-) . map fromEnum . show $ number
  -- numbers with > 3 digits have >= 2 adjacent digits (or rather differences of digits)
        , length differences > 1
  -- make sure all of these are equal by comparing them and reducing with logical and
        , and $ adjacent (==) differences
    ]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>26</s> 24 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Ç╕SôεPN^:·░ßⁿ {@ÿ}Ü╫╣1╣X
```

[Run and debug it](http://stax.tomtheisen.com/#p=80b85393ee504e5e3afab0e1fc207b40987d9ad7b931b958&i=[1,10]%0A[0,1]%0A[2,1]%0A[2,3]%0A%0A[61,86]%0A[75,90]%0A[34,74]%0A[59,81]%0A[84,85]%0A%0A[19,46]+%0A[60,81]+%0A[41,42]++%0A[13,81]+%0A[31,50]++%0A[15,42]%0A[94,99]+%0A[72,66]%0A[3189,826]++%0A%0A[15,3]%0A[22,51]+%0A[74,85]+%0A[27,31]+%0A%0A[123,0]++%0A[111,0]+%0A[111,222]+++++%0A%0A[33345,692]%0A[3894621507,5981921703]%0A[765432099,111111111]%0A%0A[1976,123]%0A&a=1&m=2)

**Explanation**

```
E{b+}99*L{E%2>|cd_E:-u%1=!C_Qf    # Full program, unpacked, implicit input
E                                 # Push all elements from array onto stack.
 {b+}99*L                         # Generate the first 99 numbers of the  Fibonacci sequence given the input
         {                   f    # Loop through all Fibonacci elements
          E                       # Array of decimal digit
           %2>                    # Does the array have at least 3 digits
              |c                  # Assume Truthy past this point
                d                 # discard top of stack
                 _E               # Copy the current element of the Fibonacci sequence and Digitize it
                  :-              # Pairwise difference of array.
                    :u            # Is there exactly 1 unique number
                        !C        # Flip the comparison, if truthy proceed
                          _Q      # Copy the current element of the Fibonacci sequence and Peek and print with a newline.
```

Not as short as I would like it and can probably be golfed a bit more, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 79 bytes

```ruby
->a,b{loop{a>99&&!(a.digits.each_cons(2).map{|a,b|a-b}|[])[1]&&p(a);a,b=b,a+b}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpLCoAgFADAs7QRJRN0F1EXEYn3@kOlZC1CPbu1HeZ68M1zm6sOOIbdWhegq2tCCgpi3Jbt9mKCYe0He3qqmDjAhfjfCBWmqA3T0hDiKLDm1xY5lJhSnrWUkiulTP4A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), <s>86</s>  81 bytes

```julia
a<b=b>=0&&((n->n>99&&2>endof(∪(diff(digits(n))))&&println(n)).([a,b]);a+b<a+2b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVNtbpwwEP3PKdz8QKBMKs/4W93lf8@A@MEmS0UVsdEu6Rl6lh6rF9naGBvSWDKyH88z8549P99fx17f7/3hdDw1R16WVTU9NVPjXFlSc55eLkP19/ef6mUcBv/5Mc63aqr9KMu36zjNr1PYfq3aHk5d/a1/PB36RzrV9@fLdJvZOL29zzd2ZFXRtgjIOwbs@zS3HWOsAw9ywIC1zpqM0YohiR0mPvE0gtWRKTfUKHBLnlYSz6iQYGSKKjOsHNiYjKS2GbYSrFpgowRmGB3INSFuqOY5BlFGJYKkBRVik4EicaXcqhAIKpaslNq4KkXQWmfUSXAulmZ2ogl0rMzaIGMNa708yngc4UxOEE1FbwOpTT4RqFilIH9rQu0SZWfCIblXQQYEpusAxL1H3nTgyX5I03sOQruNhZhYfpWmdxW8h@C9gVB/pi52r@T/SYxlmR6WCrSj9IC0kl7X5r51UhMqbkA5i47QcPGRy2PSuOPORXVRYSwgDsgH4HMedEbD8qZXGxiFqlkgAQtkv1bapHuoi2Ic2Jfx5vvsfO2f5/HXuaoLxobLlVUzsEvtG2ztsSLITS3p/z08NQ@BseBzi91hbqn7wAr/fIcXYRb3fw)

Pretty straightforward - check if input has at least 3 digits (`n>99`), then take the difference between each digit pair in the number (`diff(digits(n))`), check that the length of (`endof`) a unique set of (`∪`) those differences is 1 (i.e. all the differences are the same), and if so print the number. Do that for both the given numbers, then recursively call the function with the next two numbers.

<s>(Unfortunately, it looks like `±` has higher precedence than `+`, or else the final call could have been `a+b±a+2b`, saving 3 bytes.)</s> Now overloads the `<` operator, thus saving on both the operator bytes and the precedence brackets. (Can't use `<` in our code though, so just rearranged `endof(...)<2` to `2>endof(...)`).

If some extraneous output is allowed, we can save 2 bytes using `@show` instead of `println`, printing `n = 987` instead of just `987`. We could even use `dump` for 1 byte lower than that, but `dump` prints the type information along with the value, so output will be `Int64 987` instead of just `987`.