# Build me a castle Stairway!

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

You will be given a String consisting of printable ASCII (without newlines). Your task is to build a nice Stairway for my Castle.

## How to build a nice Stairway?

- First off, you should get all the rotations of the String. For example, the String `abcd` has the following rotations: `abcd, bcda, cdab, dabc` (each character is moved to the end until we reach the last character).
- We now place each rotation on top of each other:

  ```
  abcd
  bcda
  cdab
  dabc
  ```
- We can't really climb on a straight wall, so we must build stairs. That means you should add a number of spaces before each rotation corresponding to its index in the rotation list:

  ```
  abcd
   bcda
    cdab
     dabc
  ```
- You also need a Stairway that links to the other side of my castle, so you should build one like below, reversing each rotation and adding some spacing:

  ```
  abcd      dcba
   bcda    adcb
    cdab  badc
     dabccbad
  ```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), hence the shortest code in bytes wins and standard rules for the tag apply.

---

## Test Cases

- Input: `abcd`, Output:

  ```
  abcd      dcba
   bcda    adcb
    cdab  badc
     dabccbad
  ```
- Input: `aaaa`, Output:

  ```
  aaaa      aaaa
   aaaa    aaaa
    aaaa  aaaa
     aaaaaaaa
  ```
- Input: `Code golf`, Output (Notice the spaces):

  ```
  Code golf                flog edoC
   ode golfC              Cflog edo 
    de golfCo            oCflog ed  
     e golfCod          doCflog e   
       golfCode        edoCflog     
       golfCode        edoCflog     
        olfCode g    g edoCflo      
         lfCode go  og edoCfl       
          fCode gollog edoCf
  ```

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/13401#13401)

Comment: Shouldn't the stairway start going up, and then go down, instead of going down, then up? :P

Comment: @StepHen For the purpose of this challenge, it shouldn't :p

Comment: [Closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/111938/31716)

Comment: `dab`c. -------

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 12 bytes

#### Code:

```
vDNúsÀ}\».B∞
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/zMXv8K7iww21MYd26zk96pj3/79zfkqqQnp@ThoA)

#### Explanation:

```
v     }        # Length input times, do.. (N = iteration count)
 DNú           #   Duplicate and prepend N spaces
    sÀ         #   Swap and rotate one to the left
       \       # Discard the top of the stack
        »      # Join the stack by newlines
         .B    # Pad with spaces into a rectangle
           ∞   # Mirror the string
```

Comment: [I generated some interesting output...](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/zMXP7XBDrd/hXbWaek6POub9/@@cn5KqkJ6fkwYA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 bytes

```
J’ɓ⁹⁶ẋ;"ṙz⁶Zm€0Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/rUcPMk5MfNe581Ljt4a5ua6WHO2dWAdlRuY@a1hhE/v//XykxKTlFCQA)

Of course, -1 using [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan)'s `ɓ`!

Comment: My solution is too similar methinks, here you go: `J’ɓ⁹⁶ẋ;"ṙz⁶Zm€0Y` (or `LḶ` for `J’`)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Heh.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 85 bytes

```python
x=input()
l=len(x)
for i in range(l):y=x[i:]+x[:i];print(' '*i+y+'  '*(l+~i)+y[::-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcYxDkIhDADQ/Z@iG62Ng3GrYXLwEITBRL42IYUQTGD5V0ff9Orsn2LXtYZXq9@OtGWfk@GgbS8NFNSgPe2dMJNMP4JK5BFE4602tY4O3El5soN/MPOhxDOInC@R1rqXV4JHyfsP)

-1 byte thanks to ovs
-1 byte thanks to Lynn
-4 bytes thanks to p1131

Comment: `l-i-1` can just be `l+~i` as `~i == -i-1`

Comment: `' '*(l+~i)*2` equals `'  '*(l+~i)`, which is one byte shorter!

Comment: You can save 4 bytes by ommiting the assignment to `j` and putting the expression directly in the `print()`! [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcYxDkIhDADQ/Z@iG62Ng3GrYXLwEITBRL42IYUQTGD5V0ff9Orsn2LXtYZXq9@OtGWfk@GgbS8NFNSgPe2dMJNMP4JK5BFE4602tY4O3El5soN/MPOhxDOInC@R1rqXV4JHyfsP "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 47 bytes

```
.
$.`$* $&$'$`$.'$* ¶
%(`^
$_¶
O$^`.(?=.*$)

¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fj0tFL0FFS0FFTUVdJUFFTx3IPrSNS1UjIY5LJR7I8leJS9DTsLfV01LR5OICCvz/75yfkqqQnp@TBgA) Explanation: The first stage creates the left stairway by considering each character and creating spaces equal to the current position, then the remainder of the string, then the start of the string, then spaces equal to the remainder of the string. The rest of the script runs over each line just generated in turn. First the line is duplicated, then the characters in the duplicate are reversed, then the line and its duplicate are concatenated.

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 27 bytes

```
[:(,.|.)i.@#(|.,~' '#~[)"{]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o600dPRq9DQz9RyUNWr0dOrUFdSV66I1lapj/2typSZn5CukKagnJiWnqP8HAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <strike>23 21</strike> 20 bytes

```
ＦＬθ«ＦＬθ§θ⁺κι↘ＭＬθ←»‖Ｃ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9nmXv96w5t@PQajhr@bkdjxp3ndt1buejthnv96wFiz5qm3Bo96OGae/3LP7/3zk/JdU9PycNAA)

Can probably be golfed more, but I'm posting from the mobile app. Link to [the verbose version](https://tio.run/##XcxBCsIwEIXhfU8xyxlIL9CuSgURKkhvUJJJEwwZG0NVxLPHulFw@/2Pp92UtEyhFCsJcOA4Z4cLETwrgD/bBOCUfMzY5UM0fMdFQWcMnpUnonYbHGVlbHZyi6OfXf7Z90ZBM7D9lFc1sg2scy@XB1JbSi@G9xJsqddSX8Mb).

Comment: Oh btw if you don't add an explanation at least use [-a flag](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9nmXv96w5t@PQajhr@bkdjxp3ndt1buejthnv96wFiz5qm3Bo96OGae/3LP7/P1rJOT8lVSE9PydNKfa/biIA) pls

Comment: @ASCII-only sorry, I thought the verbose version counted as an explanation.

Comment: Wait what nvm didn't see that

Comment: I don't think it was true at the time but these days you can fill a polygon with an arbitrary string and get exactly the result you need for 9 bytes: `Ｇ→↘←Ｌθθ‖Ｃ`.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 126 bytes

```c
i,j,k,l;f(char*s){for(l=strlen(s),i=0;i<l;i++,puts(""))for(j=0;j<4*l-2;j++,putchar(i<=k&k<i+l?s[k%l]:32))k=j<2*l-1?j:4*l-3-j;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzBDoIwEAXP8hWkiaYLJVHwRNtw8DOMB1IBt13BUDwRvr3SeHvJzDxTDMaEgMIKJ0j23LzaOfOw9tPMSftlpm7kHgTqs0RFEvNcfL6L54wBRMnuwKprRkUp7R/GD45Ku5NTmFPj7@5Ij7oqAZy2qtzdS2Pr2FSFlVvAcUnfLY48jhbW5NBzdpueXTpM1DOQyRZ@)

Comment: 125 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxBDoMgFAXX9RSGpA1fIKnalUBc9BhNF4aqBX61Ebsynp3KbpI3b4wYjYnRcsc9RzlQ8@6WIsA2zAtFHdYF@4kG4FaLUjJmFcrvbw2UEIDkOH2VTt0KFJV0jPFjTAlqlfYXryzDNjz8GZ9NXQF47VR1uGXrmvSphZN7tNOafzo70QQdbNlpoOQ@v/p8nHEgILM9/gE "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, <s>80</s> 79 bytes

```
(s:u)#t|q<-(t>>" ")++s:u++t++(u>>" ")=q++reverse q++'\n':u#(t++[s])
u#_=u
(#"")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYoxDgIhEEV7TjEZTBYy8QIb2cZ2O0s1hmRBjQguMFbeHUksfdXP@@9my8OF0JoqI2tZP@tuq@o0IaAm6o6oEin@GbMSZfd2uTjoczjFYWSpenEsZy1YXgwLb5RE1O1p7xEMLEkAwIvroeY5wgY84D4t7pqCx//LdrB9AQ)

How it works

```
(#"")                      -- start with the input string and an empty accumulator

(s:u)#t                    -- let s be the first char and u the rest of the input
                           -- string, and t the accumulator
    |q<-                   -- let q be half of the current line, i.e.
        (t>>" ")++         --   length of t times spaces
        s:u++              --   s and u (aka the input string)
        t++                --   the accumulator
        (u>>" ")           --   length of u times spaces
    = q ++ reverse q ++    -- the current line is q and q reversed
        '\n' :             -- and a newline
        u#(t++[s])         -- and a recursive call with u as the new input
                           -- string and s put at the end of t
_#_=[]                     -- base case: stop if the input string is empty
```

Edit: Thanks to @Ørjan Johansen for a byte.

Comment: `u#_=u` saves a byte.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen: I first had a list of strings and `unlines` where `u#_=u` does not type check and later switched to building a single string ... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), <s>26 24 23</s> 20 bytes

```
L(DL‹n-ð$*+mðn*$+,1Ǔ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=L%28DL%E2%80%B9n-%C3%B0%24*%2Bm%C3%B0n*%24%2B%2C1%C7%93&inputs=Code%20golf&header=&footer=)

Thanks to lyxal for -3 bytes

Comment: [Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=L%28DL%E2%80%B9n-%C3%B0%24*%2Bm%C3%B0n*%24%2B%2C1%C7%93&inputs=Code%20golf&header=&footer=) for 20

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 19 bytes

```
jms_BdC.tm+*d;.<QdU
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jms_BdC.tm%2B%2ad%3B.%3CQdU&input=%22Code+golf%22&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 22 bytes

```
l
VÇç +UéZn)+´Vç)ê1Ã·
```

Leading newline is part of the program.

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?code=CmwKVsfnICtV6VpuKSu0Vucp6jHDtw==&input=IkNvZGUgZ29sZiIK)

[Run all test cases](https://codepen.io/justinm53/full/NvKjZr?code=CmwKVsfnICtV6VpuKSu0Vucp6jHDtw==&inputs=ImFiY2Qi,ImFhYWEi,IkNvZGUgZ29sZiI=) using my WIP CodePen.

### Explanation

Implicit: `U` = input string. First line is blank to not overwrite `U`.

Second line implicitly assigns the length (`l`) of `U` to `V`.

Third line:

```
VÇç +UéZn)+´Vç)ê1Ã·
VoZ{Zç +UéZn)+--Vç)ê1} · Ungolfed
VoZ{                 }   Create array [0, V) and map by...
    Zç                      The current value (Z) times " "
       +UéZn)               Concatenated with U rotated Z times left
             +--Vç)         Concatenated with --V times " ". This decrements V
                   ê1       Palindromize with repeated last char
                       · Join with newlines and implicitly output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>85</s> 83 bytes

- Thanks @ovs for 2 bytes: `l+~i` and helped me spot a unwanted space

```python
x=input()
l=len(x)
for i in range(l):r=i*' '+x[i:]+x[:i]+(l+~i)*' ';print r+r[::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcixCsMgEADQPV9xmxrJkI5XnPoZwaEQTQ@OUw4LZumv22R5w6tn@xR5jNEDSf026yYOnMR2N@WiQEAC@pYjWXaogWYDxveNMF4iRW/Z/8jd/axK0kC9bojLGscwr7InOApn8wc)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 119 bytes

```
b=StringRotateLeft;j=Table;Column@j[""<>{" "~j~i,b[s=#,i],j["  ",t-i],b[StringReverse@s,-i]},{i,0,t=StringLength@#-1}]&
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 95 bytes

```php
for($e=strlen($s=$argn);$i<$e;$s.=$s[$i],$s[$i++]=" ")echo$t=str_pad($s,2*$e-1),strrev($t),"
";
```

Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/84fe030042310b1b9f67e56ed3b98130fedb5723).

**breakdown**

```php
for($e=strlen($s=$argn);    # import input
    $i<$e;                  # loop length times
    $s.=$s[$i],                 # 2. append current character
    $s[$i++]=" ")               # 3. set current character to space
    echo$t=str_pad($s,2*$e-1),  # 1. print string padded with length-1 spaces
        strrev($t),             #    print reverse
        "\n";                   #    print newline
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 20 bytes

```
jms_B.>+.<Qd*\ tlQdl
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jms_B.%3E%2B.%3CQd%2a%5C+tlQdl&input=%22Code+golf%22&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## [8th](http://8th-dev.com/), <s>173</s> 168 bytes

**Code**

```
s:len n:1- ( >r dup s:len n:1- "" ( " " s:+ ) rot times dup 0 r@ s:slice -rot r> -1 s:slice s:+ s:+ dup s:rev swap . . cr null s:/ a:shift a:push "" a:join ) 0 rot loop
```

**Ungolfed version with comments**

```
: shifter \ s -- s
  null s:/     \ convert string into array
  a:shift      \ remove the first item in the array and put it on TOS
  a:push       \ append the former 1st item to array
  "" a:join    \ convert array into string
;

: stairway \ s -- s
  s:len n:1-
  (
    >r                       \ save loop index
    dup                      \ duplicate input string 
    s:len n:1-               \ get string length
    "" ( " " s:+ ) rot times \ make filler
    dup                      \ duplicate filler 
    0 r@ s:slice             \ make left filler
    -rot                     \ put left filler at proper position
    r> -1 s:slice            \ make right filler
    s:+ s:+                  \ build string ( 1st half of stairway )
    dup s:rev                \ build 2nd half 
    swap . . cr              \ print it
    shifter                  \ shift rotate 1st character
  ) 0 rot loop               \ loop from 0 to len(string)-1
;
```

**Usage and examples**

```
ok> "abcd" s:len n:1- ( >r dup s:len n:1- "" ( " " s:+ ) rot times dup 0 r@ s:slice -rot r> -1 s:slice s:+ s:+ dup s:rev swap . . cr null s:/ a:shift a:push "" a:join ) 0 rot loop
abcd      dcba
 bcda    adcb 
  cdab  badc  
   dabccbad
```

Or more clearly

```
ok> "Code golf" stairway
Code golf                flog edoC
 ode golfC              Cflog edo 
  de golfCo            oCflog ed  
   e golfCod          doCflog e   
     golfCode        edoCflog     
     golfCode        edoCflog     
      olfCode g    g edoCflo      
       lfCode go  og edoCfl       
        fCode gollog edoCf
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (ES6), 118 bytes

```js
s=>[...s].map((_,y)=>Array(l=(j=s.length)*4-2).fill().map((_,x)=>(x=x<l/2?x:l-x-1)>=y&y+j>x?s[x%j]:" ").join``).join`
`
```

Example code snippet:

```js
f=
s=>[...s].map((_,y)=>Array(l=(j=s.length)*4-2).fill().map((_,x)=>(x=x<l/2?x:l-x-1)>=y&y+j>x?s[x%j]:" ").join``).join`
`
o.innerText=f("Code golf")
```

```html
<pre id=o>
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 29 bytes

```apl
{w←⍵⋄(⊢,⌽)↑{(-⍵+⍴w)↑⍵⌽w}¨⍳⍴⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/6vLgdSj3q2Puls0HnUt0nnUs1fzUdvEag1doKD2o94t5SAuSEHP3vLaQyse9W4GCgL5tf/TwDr7HnU1P@pdAxQ8tN4YpLRvanCQM5AM8fAM/p@moJ6YlJyizgUUACpXV@cCiQABqohzfkqqQnp@Tpo6FxcA)

### Explanation

```apl
{w←⍵⋄(⊢,⌽)↑{(-⍵+⍴w)↑⍵⌽w}¨⍳⍴⍵} ⍵ → input
 w←⍵                          assign original input to w
                         ⍳⍴⍵  range from 0 to length of ⍵
           {           }¨     map range to function, loop var i
                    ⍵⌽w       input rotated i characters
            (-⍵+⍴w)           i + length of input, negated
                   ↑          take that much from the rotated string
                              (prepends spaces)
          ↑                   mix the array to create one side of the pattern
     (⊢,⌽)                    append the reverse of the matrix to itself
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-lF -M5.10.0`, 57 bytes

```perl
@F=@F[1..$#F,!say$"x$-,@F,"  "x($#F-$-++),reverse@F]for@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9r6Jra2D938HN1sEt2lBPT0XZTUexOLFSRalCRVfHwU1HSUFBqUIDKKyroqutralTlFqWWlSc6uAWm5Zf5OD2/39iUnIKVyIQcDnnp6QqpOfnpP3LLyjJzM8r/q@b4/Zf19dUz9BAzwAA)

### Explanation

Using `-F` (specifying the `-F` switch without an argument, `-F` controls how a string is split into `@F`) the input is split into a list of singular chars. `for` each char in `@F`, `@F` is then set to the slice of index `1` to `$#F` (which is the last index in `@F`) followed by the item at index `!say...` which equates to `0`. The effectively shifts the list content backwards by one index each iteration. `say` is called within the indexing operation to produce the output before the list is re-indexed and is provided with `$"x$-` (`$-`, which is a special int only variable that is preinitialised to `0`, copies of `$"`, which is the special list separator variable, preinitialised to space) followed by `@F`, followed by `"  "x($#F-$-++)` (two spaces repeated by the final index of `@F` with the current value of `$-` times - `$-` is post-incremented here so will increase on the next iteration), finally followed by the `reverse` of `@F`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 82 bytes

```python
x=input()
i=l=-len(x)
while i:s=x[i:]+x[:i];i+=1;print' '*(~l+i)+s+'  '*-i+s[::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DccxDgIhEAXQfk9BtgGcUKwlm6k8BqET3Z9MgAhmsfHq6Ote/fSj5Oucg5Hruxu7gIWdpGyGXc4DkhR84xHgI43gEXcQb3t9IXet9MV8hWCpkVb/OVAL3rstzrneyj2pZ5HH@gM)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-l`, 21 bytes

```
aMERF:sX#aRA_a@Y_+,#a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/0dc1yM2qOEI5McgxPtEhMl5bRznx////ujn/E5OSUwA)

#### Explanation

```
                       a is command-line argument; s is space (implicit)
aME                    Map this function to each number in 0 .. len(a)-1:
                  ,#a   Range(len(a))
                _+      Add the function's argument: Range(_, _+len(a))
               Y        Yank that range (just to get the precedence right)
             a@         Use the range as the (modular) indices to slice into the string
      sX#a              Get a string of spaces of the same length as the input string
          RA_           Replace the space at index _ with the slice calculated above
   RF:                  Reflect the string, appending its reverse to it
                       Output the result list one item per line (-l flag)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 15 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
¬£éYn)iYçÃú mê1
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=rKPpWW4paVnnw/ogbeox&input=IkNvZGUgZ29sZiI)

```
¬£éYn)iYçÃú mê1     :Implicit input of string U
¬                   :Split
 £                  :Map each character at 0-based index Y
  é                 :  Rotate U right
   Yn               :    -Y times
     )              :  End rotate
      i             :  Prepend
       Yç           :    Space repeated Y times
         Ã          :End map
          ú         :Right pad with spaces to the length of the longest
            m       :Map
             ê1     :  Mirror
                    :Implicit output joined with newlines
```