# Decode the Dreaded Alphabet Cypher™️

Tags: code-golf, encryption

This challenge is inspired by one of my other challenges: [Pointlessly make your way down the alphabet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/196192/)

That challenge asked you to take a string of text, and for each letter produce a sequence of letters moving down the alphabet to 'a'.

For this challenge I'd like to decode the output of that challenge (minus the line breaks), to find a human-readable string from a much longer human readable string.

---

Here is some text which has been encoded using the Dreaded Alphabet Cypher™️

hgfedcbaedcbalkjihgfedcbalkjihgfedcbaonmlkjihgfedcba wvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbaonmlkjihgfedcbarqponmlkjihgfedcbalkjihgfedcbadcba

It consists of descending alphabetical sequences, ending in an 'a'. The first character in each of these sequences is a letter in the decoded text. (A space is still a space).

## The challenge

- Write code to convert a Dreaded Alphabet Cypher™️ encoded string into a decoded, human-readable string.
- No need to validate if it is a Dreaded Alphabet Cypher™️ string, I'm not interested in how it handles invalid input.
- Use any language you please.
- Please include a link to an online iterpreter.
- The input will only consist of lower-case letters and spaces. No upper cases, punctuation etc.
- Code golf, try to write short code, standard loopholes etc.

## Test Cases

Input:

```
hgfedcbaedcbalkjihgfedcbalkjihgfedcbaonmlkjihgfedcba wvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbaonmlkjihgfedcbarqponmlkjihgfedcbalkjihgfedcbadcba
```

Output:

```
hello world
```

---

Input:

```
abacbadcbaedcbafedcbagfedcbahgfedcbaihgfedcbajihgfedcbakjihgfedcbalkjihgfedcbamlkjihgfedcbanmlkjihgfedcbaonmlkjihgfedcbaponmlkjihgfedcbaqponmlkjihgfedcbarqponmlkjihgfedcbasrqponmlkjihgfedcbatsrqponmlkjihgfedcbautsrqponmlkjihgfedcbavutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbawvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbaxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbayxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba
```

Output:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

---

(beware the multiple a's)

Input:

```
aarqponmlkjihgfedcbaonmlkjihgfedcbanmlkjihgfedcba a aarqponmlkjihgfedcbaonmlkjihgfedcbanmlkjihgfedcbasrqponmlkjihgfedcbaonmlkjihgfedcbanmlkjihgfedcba hgfedcbaasrqponmlkjihgfedcba anmlkjihgfedcba aarqponmlkjihgfedcbadcbavutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbaarqponmlkjihgfedcbakjihgfedcba
```

Output:

```
aaron a aaronson has an aardvark
```

---

Input:

```
hgfedcbaaponmlkjihgfedcbaponmlkjihgfedcbayxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba gfedcbaonmlkjihgfedcbalkjihgfedcbafedcbaihgfedcbanmlkjihgfedcbagfedcba
```

Output (is a secret, shh)

Comment: May the input contain leading or trailing spaces, or several spaces in a row?

Comment: @Arnauld I'm happy with trailing and leading spaces, but not within the result itself.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the _input_, not the output. (I've edited my previous comment.)

Comment: @Arnauld The input could have trailing and leading spaces.

Comment: May our input & output types differ (e.g. string in, list of characters out?) - maybe we have a meta consensus...?

Comment: @JonathanAllan sounds fine to me

Comment: *Alexa, announce "hgfedcbaedcbalkjihgfedcbalkjihgfedcbaonmlkjihgfedcba wvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbaonmlkjihgfedcbarqponmlkjihgfedcbalkjihgfedcbadcba"*

Answer (score 16):

## JavaScript (ES9),  <s>37 33</s>  26 bytes

Returns an array of characters.

Either a negative look-behind:

```javascript
s=>s.match(/(?<![b-z])./g)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVJLEoIwDN17CmRDu6BcQPQgjovyB4EiRVQuXxUBoaSg02knTV@Sl9cktKbcLeOiMnPm@SKwBbf3nGS0ciNkocNue3TM5oSJFWLhspyz1CcpC1GA9CgMfM91aHuk5yTuHWOb5dn4qt3qa8XLSyH5pescMLbfW8ckYXGODAPjjUSMOrRDtfBPUBfb5xiSfdMqqk1oLLKWOc@amLcFSAHJA2oGK6kQ@K7wP1QPjfJlUXq6@rfSQLzWvzH83xq9AUVqM0IAHbXcAPhHqYYMxcoYKT9Cg5sf29KwT4EASfEE)

Or a positive look-behind:

```javascript
s=>s.match(/(?<=a| |^)./g)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVLbEoIgEH3vKxxfhIfwB7L@pBm8awomZpfx361MTWHRGgZmWc7unj1sSmsqvDIpqi3jftCGTiucvSA5rbwY2eiwc2hjNEdM7Ai3HmeCZwHJeIRCZMZRGPieS7sjO6XJ4JjanOXTq3GtL5Uoz4Xkl64qYGq/t4lJyhOGLAvjjUSMurRHdfBPUB875BiTfdNqqs1oLLKWOStNqG0BUkDygJrBSmoEvmn8d93DQ/uyKD1d/VtpIF7r3xjxb43BgCINhRBARy83AP5RqjFDsTJG2o8w4OantjTscyBAsn0C)

---

### 25 bytes

If the input is guaranteed not to contain leading or double spaces (or we're allowed to remove and collapse them respectively), the positive look-behind can be made 1 byte shorter:

```javascript
s=>s.match(/(?<=a|\b)./g)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVJLEoIwDN17CoYN7cJyAdGLuCl/EFqkiJ/x7qgICG0KMp120vQleXlNSmsqvDIpqi3jftCETiOcvSA5rbwY2eiwc@jz6GJiR7jxOBM8C0jGIxQiM47CwPdc2h7ZKU16x9jmLB9fjWt9qUR5LiS/dFUBY/uzTUxSnjBkWRhvJGLUpR2qhX@Dutg@x5Dsl1ZTbUJjlrXMWWlCbQuQApIH1AxWUiPwTeO/6x4e2pdZ6eni30oD8V5rY8TaGr0BRRoKIYCOXm4A/KdUQ4ZiYYy0H2HAzY9tadinQIBk8wI)

Answer (score 13):

### Haskell, 32 bytes

```hs
f s=[y|(x,y)<-zip('a':s)s,x<'b']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVJLDoIwEL3KhJgACXoAAzdw55KwKAqCfKwU5BPvXhUpltJKSNNmPm/aN28aIZIEaUppCMRx26fRWK1pb7sYGzrS98QkVmPrvu7RDMU5OICr8lgWhxx2QKJbDRvIEIYQXC26hMH55KP@SJNrzAK8fcsz3oX6UZWkuGMhLrhzAG9/tmaBhnw0eH34mxwwDDsW/coVt06e@8tO5DYjO6cvaVkmg1QbuWIKIRtFvFUlOmWmlxgtzkoY8HutrSFr32CGrBJmhCR01LJKwIIkIxIvfAulsCBvkreFzzsFMjIefQE)

For each pair of consecutive characters, if the first one is `'a'` or `' '`, output the second one. Prepends an `'a'` to the string so that the first character is always output.

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
OŻI‘Tị
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of characters which yields a list of characters.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9//6G7PRw0zQh7u7v7//79SYmJRYUF@Xm5OdlZmRnpaakpyUiIaF5WnAISk6ikm1Q4YA5tOBQwHYXEOCJeVlmDRjkUxElMJAA)**

#### How?

```
OŻI‘Tị - Link: list of characters, S   e.g. "  baadcba  acbaedcba  "
                                       i.e. [' ',' ','b','a','a','d','c','b','a',' ',' ','a','c','b','a','e','d','c','b','a',' ',' ']
O      - to ordinal (vectorises across S)   [ 32, 32, 98, 97, 97,100, 99, 98, 97, 32, 32, 97, 99, 98, 97,101,100, 99, 98, 97, 32, 32]
 Ż     - prepend a zero                 [  0, 32, 32, 98, 97, 97,100, 99, 98, 97, 32, 32, 97, 99, 98, 97,101,100, 99, 98, 97, 32, 32]
  I    - incremental differences            [ 32,  0, 66, -1,  0,  3, -1, -1, -1,-65,  0, 65,  2, -1, -1,  4, -1, -1, -1, -1,-65,  0]
   ‘   - increment (vectorises)             [ 33,  1, 67,  0,  1,  4,  0,  0,  0,-64,  1, 66,  3,  0,  0,  5,  0,  0,  0,  0,-64,  1]
    T  - truthy indices                     [  1,  2,  3,      5,  6,             10, 11, 12, 13,         16,                 21, 22]
     ị - index into (S)                     [' ',' ','b',    'a','d',             ' ',' ','a','c',       'e',                ' ',' ']
                                       i.e. "  bad  ace  "
```

Answer (score 9):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>22 13</s> 12 bytes

–9 bytes, thanks @Jonah!

```
#~1,1-{:I.}:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/lesMdQx1q6089Wqt/mtypSZn5CukKahnpKelpiQnJSYW5Ofl5mRnZcIE0PmVFeVlpSXFRYXoEgpQGk0YmQ0h4VxUhVBKHe6kxERMS9C4aC4AQlL1FJNqBzygsAUBhoOwOAeEsYcgFsVITPX/AA)

Comment: 13 bytes: `#~1,98>3 u:}:` ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/lesMdSwt7IwVSq1qrf5rcqUmZ@QrpCmoZ6SnpaYkJyUmFuTn5eZkZ2XCBND5lRXlZaUlxUWF6BIKUBpNGJkNIeFcVIVQSh3upMRETEvQuGguAEJS9RSTagc8oLAFAYaDsDgHhLGHIBbFSEz1/wA "J – Try It Online"))

Answer (score 8):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) (`-p`), <s>15</s>, 16 bytes

```perl
s/[b-z]\K.*?a//g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YPzpJtyo2xltPyz5RXz/9//@M9LTUlOSkRDCRk52VCRNAZufn5SJzFcrLSkuKiwoL0MTRuJgKkNkgzJWYlAhlgsUgMlAFMIVwHQi9OIxEsQuv09AdhuFSTLdj8S@2MMAaMNiDC0coVuAQr8QlUYVThisxkWAsoUUtEJKqp5hUO2AMbDoVMByExTm4wxSLYuTwgCsrIJAgcAapAnYfIrPRki2qQij1L7@gJDM/r/i/bgEA)

or using options trick

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) (`-nF/(?<![\x20a])(?!^)[b-z]*a/`), 7 bytes

```perl
print@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvxMHt//@M9LTUlOSkRDCRk52VCRNAZufn5SJzFcrLSkuKiwoL0MTRuJgKkNkgzJWYlAhlgsUgMlAFMIVwHQi9OIxEsQuv09AdhuFSTLdj8S@2MMAaMNiDC0coVuAQr8QlUYVThisxkWAsoUUtEJKqp5hUO2AMbDoVMByExTm4wxSLYuTwgCsrIJAgcAapAnYfIrPRki2qQij1L7@gJDM/r/i/bp6bvoa9jWJ0TIWRQWKspoa9YpxmdJJuVaxWoj4A)

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 43 bytes

```python
lambda s:[r for l,r in zip(' '+s,s)if'b'>l]
```

An unnamed function accepting a string which returns a list of characters.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYKrpIIS2/SCFHp0ghM0@hKrNAQ11BXbtYp1gzM009Sd0uJ/Z/SWpxiYKtgnpiYlFhQX5ebk52VmZGelpqSnJSIhoXlacAhKTqKSbVDhgDm04FDAdhcQ4Il5WWYNGORTESU52Lq6AoM69EI00DFEKamv8B)**

---

To accept & return lists use `...zip([' ']+s...` instead (45)

To accept & return strings use `lambda s:''.join(r for l,r in zip(' '+s,s)if'b'>l)` (50)

Answer (score 8):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>100</s> <s>98</s> <s>96</s> <s>95</s> <s>94</s> <s>92</s> <s>90</s> <s>88</s> <s>64</s> 46 bytes

Saved 24 bytes thanks to @Neil!!!
Saved 18 bytes thanks to @dingledooper (removed #include<stdio.h>)

```c
f(char*c){while(*c)for(putchar(*c);*c++>97;);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVPbDoIwDH3nKxaehsTEN2OW@CW@jMlNceAA8RK/HQfCxNGJQEbarj07PStsyRLKw7oOMIuoWDDnUUVx4mNpBanAWVk08cYlC@a6282aOORZx7xAJxpz7FgPC8knwHYUBv6eebT9JMdD3AeGdspPQxdVl7LIxTnT4po7ThjazbId0vLIhKQmyex4H5EO9WiX1ua/q7riHkShfXANx9ktLEL2F6Gf/HX2o3YU5rhTQB1IMVBGBQurbBD/aogrtJsp427c@X0/dHICtLGR79yafO4ZvQFVohEhgE6zYDWA5H@1UhDZxIwZrwLB3Q9t7Zf4TtRYCr8oBUcrYj2t@gU)

Comment: Why not just `while(*n>97)`?

Comment: Also, by putting `putchar(*c);` before the `while` loop, I was able to replace all uses of `n` with `c`.

Comment: In fact, by changing the `while` loop into a `for` loop you can move the `putchar(*c)` into the initialiser, saving you a pair of `{}`s.

Comment: @Neil Thanks so much, that's amazing!  And now I can finally have a post-increment as part of the condition expression. :-)

Comment: Thanks for posting this; the loop structure was useful for [an x86 machine code implementation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/196466/decode-the-dreaded-alphabet-cypher️/196558#196558)

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to Kevin Cruijssen*

```
AηíR¬S.:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f8dz2w2uDDq0J1rP6/z8xsaiwID8vNyc7KzMjPS01JTkpEY2LylMAQlL1FJNqB4yBTacChoOwOAeEy0pLsGjHohiJCQA)

Comment: [8 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f8dz2oMNrD60J1rP6/z8xsaiwID8vNyc7KzMjPS01JTkpEY2LylMAQlL1FJNqB4yBTacChoOwOAeEy0pLsGjHohiJCQA) by replacing `ASR` with `¬S`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Nice catch, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-g`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>10</s> <s>9</s> 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
óÈ¥YcÄÃy
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWc&code=88ilWWPEw3k&input=ImhnZmVkY2JhZWRjYmFsa2ppaGdmZWRjYmFsa2ppaGdmZWRjYmFvbm1sa2ppaGdmZWRjYmEgd3Z1dHNycXBvbm1sa2ppaGdmZWRjYmFvbm1sa2ppaGdmZWRjYmFycXBvbm1sa2ppaGdmZWRjYmFsa2ppaGdmZWRjYmFkY2JhIg)

```
ó           split between those characters that return true when passed through...
 È    Ã     function :
  ¥         x equal to..
   YcÄ      character next to y
       y   transpose

Flag -g used to get 1st element
```

Saved 1 thanks to @Shaggy

Comment: `1dYc` can be `YcÄ`

Comment: I don't know why `ó>` or `ò<` won't work here; was trying them earlier.

Comment: I was trying something similar too but nothing worked

Comment: And yet ... https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=UzwnYQ

Comment: @Shaggy i moved to japt chat

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>57</s> 56 bytes

-1 byte thanks to Giuseppe.

```r
function(s)intToUtf8(c(v<-utf8ToInt(s),0)[c(0,v)%%32<2])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jWDMzryQkP7QkzUIjWaPMRrcUyArJ98wrAUrpGGhGJ2sY6JRpqqoaG9kYxWr@T9NQykhPS01JTkoEEznZWZkwAWR2fl4uMlehvKy0pLiosABNHI2LqQCZDcJKmlxAJyQmJUL5YAmINFQVTDVcG8IAHOaiWIjXfeiuw3AupgeweBpbQGANHexhhiMoK3CIV@KSqMIpAw3kRILxhRbJQEiqnmJS7YAxsOlUwHAQFufgDlgsijECBa62gEDSwBm4Cti9icxGS8CoClHjSEnzPwA)

Could probably be made shorter with a regex, but this is more R-like. Converts to integers (vector `v`), then keeps only the first character and the characters which follow a space or an `a`. Since the corresponding codepoints are 32 and 97, we can check whether \$v_i\mod 32 <2\$ to get the relevant entries.

Comment: [56 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jWDMzryQkP7QkzUIjWaPMRrcUyArJ98wrAUrpGGhGJ2sY6JRpqqoaG9kYxWr@T9NQykhPS01JTkoEEznZWZkwAWR2fl4uMlehvKy0pLiosABNHI2LqQCZDcJKmlxAJyQmJUL5YAmINFQVTDVcG8IAHOaiWIjXfeiuw3AupgeweBpbQGANHexhhiMoK3CIV@KSqMIpAw3kRILxhRbJQEiqnmJS7YAxsOlUwHAQFufgDlgsijECBa62gEDSwBm4Cti9icxGS8CoClHjSEnzPwA) using in-line assignment instead of a function argument

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript, <s>35</s> <s>32</s> 31 bytes

```
s=>s.replace(/ |.*?a/g,x=>x[0])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/Y1q5Yryi1ICcxOVVDX6FGT8s@UT9dp8LWriLaIFbzf3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RpqGUkZ6WmpKclIimMjJzsqECSCz8/NykbkK5WWlJcVFhQVo4mhcTAXIbBBW0tT8DwA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 59 bytes

```hs
f""=""
f(x:s)|x<'b'=x:(f s)|1>0=x:(f$tail$dropWhile(>'a')s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVJBDoIwELzziqYhAW56JcILvHnwXIQKUqBS0Gr8e0UEhNJKCIHM7s6ys9PGiKURIUJgCD0IDWxzlzkvvrMCy@OujUETbf1Ni80KJcQMy4Ie44REtm8hy2GOyFCSe2FhAFpXh6rc5yYGMD7jKDwFqP2Q9JL0iTEu8mwcgvutrlh5pVJeCueEMf68cKoFBagrtIwvr6P3bUP/70@aAZPJf4XKMme655sotlc5orRJbZ7GU67JP3SFp7Yiu40WT1A69uZZ28PWzuiBqhPMBCnk6B1WkPXuDE104bJo7QbqfcdYutJTYq9LvAE)

No match for regex solutions, but I figured I'd try a recursive solution.

Comment: [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##lVJBDoIwELzzioY0AW56JcILvPmCRaggUJGCVuPfKyIglFZCCGR2d5adnTYGlkZZJgSxucucF99ZgeVx1yaoibb@psW4giTDjIaYFUBt3wLLYY5BEPe4yCGhXngxUFFXh6rcU0yQGZ9IFB4DaD9Zek76xBhfaD4O0f1WV6y8FlJeCueEMf685lQLBNAVWsaX19H7tqH/9yfNgMnkv0JlmTPd800U26scUdqkNk/jKdfkH7rCU1uR3YbFE5SOvXnW9rC1M3qg6kQzQQo5eocVZL07Q1OxcFm0diP1vmMsXekpsdcl3g)

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-S`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>9</s> 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
¸®ò§ mÎ¬
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVM&code=uK7ypyBtzqw&input=ImFhcnFwb25tbGtqaWhnZmVkY2Jhb25tbGtqaWhnZmVkY2Jhbm1sa2ppaGdmZWRjYmEgYSBhYXJxcG9ubWxramloZ2ZlZGNiYW9ubWxramloZ2ZlZGNiYW5tbGtqaWhnZmVkY2Jhc3JxcG9ubWxramloZ2ZlZGNiYW9ubWxramloZ2ZlZGNiYW5tbGtqaWhnZmVkY2JhIGhnZmVkY2JhYXNycXBvbm1sa2ppaGdmZWRjYmEgYW5tbGtqaWhnZmVkY2JhIGFhcnFwb25tbGtqaWhnZmVkY2JhZGNiYXZ1dHNycXBvbm1sa2ppaGdmZWRjYmFhcnFwb25tbGtqaWhnZmVkY2Jha2ppaGdmZWRjYmEi)

```
¸®ò§ mÎ¬    :Implicit input of string
¸           :Split on spaces
 ®          :Map
  ò         :  Partition between characters where
   §        :  First is <= second
     m      :  Map
      Î     :    First character
       ¬    :  Join
            :Implicit output, joined with spaces
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/), 28 bytes

```
->s{s.scan(/(?<=a|\b)./)*""}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664ulivODkxT0Nfw97GNrEmJklTT19TS0mp9n9BaUmxQppecmJOjoZ6RnpaakpyUiKYyMnOyoQJILPz83KRuQrlZUAjigoL0MTRuJgKkNkgrK7JxYXimsSkRKgUWA1EJVQDTCPcBIRZOKxAsRuvU9EdiuFyTL9g8T@2MMEaUNiDD0eoVuAQr8QlUYVTBjO8EwnGIlrUAyGpeopJtQPGwKZTAcNBWJyDO4yxKMYXPnBtBQQSDM4gV8DuY2Q2WrJGVQh32X8A)

This is a port of [Arnauld's Javascript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/196466/decode-the-dreaded-alphabet-cypher%ef%b8%8f/196467#196467) to Ruby.

Answer (score 5):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 14 bytes

```
{x@&1,98>-1_x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qusJBzVDH0sJO1zC@ovZ/mrqGUkZ6WmpKclIimMjJzsqECSCz8/NykbkK5WWlJcVFhQVo4mhcTAXIbBBWslZKTEqEcsCiEDmoEphSuB6EbhyGotiG13HoTsNwK6brsfgYWyhgDRrsAYYjHCtwiFfikqjCKQMK4USCMYUWvUBIqp5iUu2AMbDpVMBwEBbn4A5VLIpRQwSusIBAosAZrArY/YjMRku6qAphbtH8DwA)

Inspired by [FrownyFrog's/Jonah's J solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/196475/75681)

Answer (score 4):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 106 bytes

```
	I =INPUT
S	I LEN(1) . X	:F(O)
	O =O X
	R =
	REVERSE(&LCASE) X REM . R
	I X R REM . I	:(S)
O	OUTPUT =O
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9NTwdbTLyA0hCsYyPRx9dMw1FTQU4jgtHLT8Nfk4vRXsPVXiODiDFKwBRKuYa5Bwa4aaj7OjsGumgoRCkGuvkDVQVxAvUAOlOvJaaURrMnlz@kfGgI0GWgCl6ufy///iYlFhQX5ebk52VmZGelpqSnJSYloXFSeAhCSqqeYRPUA)

```
	I =INPUT			;* Read input
S	I LEN(1) . X	:F(O)		;* extract the first letter or goto O if none exist
	O =O X				;* append that letter to the output
	R =				;* set R to the empty string
	REVERSE(&LCASE) X REM . R	;* Set R to the letters up to 'a', starting at X.
					;* R is empty string if X is space or 'a'
	I X R REM . I	:(S)		;* Set the REMainder of I after (X + R) to I; goto S
O	OUTPUT =O			;* output the string
END
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
Ḳµ=Ṃk⁸ZḢ)K
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjk2Htto@3NmU/ahxR9TDHYs0vf///5@YWFRYkJ@Xm5OdlZmRnpaakpyUiMZF5SkAIal6ikm1A8bAplMBw0FYnAPCZaUlWLRjUYzEBAA)

A monadic link taking a Jelly string and returning a Jelly string. When run as a full program takes a string as its argument and implicitly prints the output string.

Answer (score 4):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 33 bytes

```cs
x=>x.Where((_,l)=>l<1||x[l-1]<98)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVRdb8IgFH0ev4L4BEk18W1LP17MlizZuw/GLJRRy6zUAdVu09/eWWu1UpixpM39OBcOB26pGlLFq5dC0EBpycXCe30WxYpJEmcsoCmRUZSEVRlG5WiaMskQevcyHEZZMN7tylk2HM@Dp0dc@WBDJNRMaQVDKNh2Noe/4GGQLhL2QWNy/GTLT94GunYuVl0XbjeFVvJrbcQNtw/o2vU78A4MSExO7jHeZE@gFnyuutQ7pr1a7196Jrke2z5/y55tOljFsUvmULJ0xL9diR9nptGY3Dwt44gP494ade8arWGrhD1CFjpuXS1gU5MzdH3jYjilhfZddm3j@l4DWzZg74Mkl4zQFLVdCrlouhXXbTqVXLM3Lhhq/gKjSS4o0ShBNQZj7IM9gJ2nIuAP)

Answer (score 4):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 74 bytes

```
func[s][parse s[any[copy t thru"a"(prin#"`"+ length? t)opt[sp(prin sp)]]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVPbUsMgEH3PV@ysL@34B33xH3xlmJFyaaoVEEhr/PnYxKSlXNSGCbOXs3A4LE6K4VkKQhu1gUF1mhNPiWXOS/CE6Z5wY3sIEFrXIcOVdXv9gC/4CAepd6F9grA2NhBvpxR4u6bnb1DGScZb4EZIAQTbnZKCb9k0Hd5e90sgto1@j104Hbvg3YdN4ombA2J7/LFBtmWzM0V/cjNkgV5qrtWVRW92@5VcSi3jmrMvnLikQlGasmAVHT8r8b6W@KpmRoXZnzeVXO953Fvj791jMUqVkBEq0KmrWgDHikBzafqsC/6tOJQPGdtJ794CFzIUiJrf4vhMAyDS4Rs)

Answer (score 4):

## [braingasm](https://github.com/daniero/braingasm), <s>20</s> 18 bytes

```
,[.32-n[65-$[,]],]
```

It's been a while since I worked on braingasm. There seems to be a `compare` function, but I guess I didn't come around to implement a way to use the result. Well, this works:

```
,                    #  Read a byte from input
 [               ]   #  While the current byte is not zero
  .                  #    Print it
   32-               #    Decrease by 32
      n[       ]     #    If the result is non-zero (meaning it wasn't a space):
        65-          #      Subtract 65, leaving 'a' => 0, 'b' => 1, 'c' => 3, etc
           $[,]      #      That many times, read a byte from input
                ,    #    Read another byte
```

Doesn't handle newlines or anything other than lowercase letters and spaces in the input.

Answer (score 4):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 12 bytes

```
aR`\w*?a`_@0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/MSghplzLPjEh3sHg////GelpqSnJSYlgIic7KxMmgMzOz8tF5iqUl5WWFBcVFqCJo3ExFSCzQRgA)

#### Explanation

```
a             The input, as a command-line argument
 R            Do a regex replacement:
  `\w*?a`      Match a non-greedy series of letters ending in a
         _@0   Replace with the first character of the match
```

Answer (score 4):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>66</s> 48 bytes

edit: -18 bytes thanks to @dingledooper (removed #include)

```c
P;D(char*T){*T?P>97||putchar(*T),P=*T++,D(T):0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///P8DaRSM5I7FIK0SzWivEPsDO0rympqC0BCSmARTUCbDVCtHW1nHRCNG0MrCu/Z@ZV6KQm5iZp6HJVc2lAAQuGkqJiQoZ6WmpKclJiWAiJzsrEyaAzM7Py0XmKpSXlZYUFxUWoImjcTEVILNBWEnTGuwUmLvVY/LUoUJg1xG0As1dQEiqnmJS7YAxsOlUwHAQFueAMPbww6IYiYk/sOBmoJuAzq@swBF7Cti9j8yGkDhCBs2ZRaklpUV5CgbWXLVc/wE)

```c
int P;          // previous character
D(char*T)
{
    if (*T)     // check for end of string
    {
        if (!(P > 'a'))     // output current if previous was 'a' or ' '
            putchar(*T);
        P = *T;             // update previous
        D(T + 1);           // find next
    }
}
```

Comment: You can remove the `#include <stdio.h>`, by the way

Comment: @dingledooper that's interesting, I didn't know that C allows calling standard functions without including the appropriate header.

Comment: @xibu: It's not recommended, but yes C89 has default-promotion rules for what happens when calling a function for which no prototype exists.  If the actual definition of the function is compatible with the args you passed it, it works.  If not, UB with no detection at compile time of the mismatch.

Answer (score 4):

## x86 machine code, 12 bytes

(Runs in any mode, 16-bit, 32-bit, or 64-bit.)

This is based on [@Noodle9's C algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/196505/30206), but with rearrangement into do{}while asm loop structure.

NASM listing: address, machine code (hex dump of the actual answer), source

```
 1                             decda:  ; (char *dst=RDI, const char *src=RSI)
 2 00000000 AC                     lodsb             ; AL = *src++
 3                             .loop:                ; do{
 4 00000001 AA                     stosb                 ; *dst++ = AL
 5                                .skip_until_a:         ; do{
 6 00000002 3C61                    cmp  al, 'a'
 7 00000004 AC                      lodsb
 8 00000005 77FB                    ja  .skip_until_a    ; }while((AL=*p++) > 'a')
 9 00000007 84C0                   test al,al
10 00000009 75F6                   jnz .loop         ; } while(AL != terminator)
11                             ;    stosb             ; append a terminating 0
12 0000000B C3                     ret
                       ; output end pointer returned in RDI
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVRNbxoxED3Xv2J6ArIQQVtVEYhKkXqJFPWQHiO0ml0bcOK1tx4vgbb57XR2zceGkEqxBNgz82be84xBIlVkZjOwSMV2K1UucQwwgW6@RA8XksL07vtNH3JnKUA0ks@ndz9vegJ4GScpg/aawPUtTJuwJBGXxrlyDCdrAtL9afAU3Ak@@uvSScJ5rm/ruEt61GVa2aBNiuMzeSAvSgA0fehgJ1oaanH7gCcpIvj5aamN6navb6cXZZL04FuNjsKCYsGcD01zfLC/odHSqv0MEc96P04Z4AttMTjfE5Pz0iaAZamsBDxEa7uAYVPBqyAm/FV5SxxQOm05CIIDZ9WgRAqDGurmEJYKXBXKigE5GsNRaLxCuYEl1thMLbQ9ZlhiqDEb4CSkJFQktg1DtWa/ZaLeKCvaJs5NLwxqrYMQUs2xMoG5xltZGJehgZQC@iDizzjiCrdiTVL34d5TmVxBAlcXo9nuGvxidT@axchawp7DhwnoojQ612HA50VYgrZMBkipgkAhaeVbBVS@7rN1LeIwKtzX5PvJqvlMHKnQ/6kcmDSPQERnbEvTkbf6wRfNL6Rdn87Xl8yUucWpr7K9hfRuNKLctrba//WLaBk48@gwS3PZcuG67UrTH3fpk9dBxXIbaqQd/I2rO@pDpFmX6Ymj5jfu8ditZjwa29p5iMzUTlvDJxL69Hl0vn49TenCu6rsDnutKdiNmSCVB@0sXEoMKCKHMQRdKGKqIDPo/O3EVCtNOjMq/jeRgyfeouUuBs4BjJtz09xKeV9ZEnsKMdVoOKxzDcV2i@h/lc4W5vFBLxdzJfMMT44vT/zM3o2h99bYb84h4RWhM3Tqz4qb9dpzJri1Ff8A)

The input is an implicit-length (0-terminated) C string.  The output is an explicit-length buffer.  This function returns (in RDI) a pointer to one-past-the-end.

(The caller already knows where the output buf starts, so it has C++-like .begin and .end iterators).  Making this function append a terminating `0` would cost 1 extra byte for another `stosb` after the loop, unless there's a way to rearrange things that I'm not seeing.

---

A sample caller that passes the output of `decda(argv[1])` to a `write` system call is included in the TIO link.  You can `inc edx` in that caller to prove that the output didn't over-write beyond where it's supposed to.

I had been thinking of using `loop .loop` instead of `test al,al/jnz` but then the inner loop would need a `dec ecx` or something.  (Without that, it loops until writing RCX *output* bytes, which only works if the caller knows the decrypted length, not the source length.)  Worth considering for a 32-bit-only version that can use 1-byte `dec ecx`, unless that could reach `loop` or `loopne` with ECX<=0 for valid inputs.

Comment: Very nice!  I assembled and tested this on 16-bit MASM 1.1 and passes all tests perfectly.  :)

Comment: @640KB: cool, I only tested it on x86-64 Linux.  Well-golfed machine code is often independent of mode thanks to using implicit increments and sizes so I was pretty sure about my claim of working in any mode, but nice to have it tested :)

Comment: (Correction to my last comment: ModRM.rm memory addressing modes have a different interpretation with 16-bit address-size than with 32 or 64.  e.g. rm field = 000 is `[rax]` in 64-bit vs. `[bx+si]` in 16-bit.  So the exact same machine-code bytes working the same in 16-bit mode only happens when memory access uses `lods`/`stos` and similar, not `cmp cl, [rbx]` or whatever.)

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 69 bytes

Hard to beat Regex on this one

```cs
s=>System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(s,"([b-z]).*?a","$1")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYoxD4IwFIR3fkXTOLQGSJwRnXRyUhMH41DqA6tQsK8o@ueraEwavOTdu/tyEiOJyi1bLadojdJF@H0zkpPUYTrbPNBCFW@hs/EairYUZtE1BhBVrbFH0L29KYUEhiFl@yx6Hng8ngsa0tGEcpcEO6MsrJQGljN6KnI4ykx8rLyc1Q/4udaVX8n91lo012bAB/V/4Of@KOdJQDy5Fw)

**Returns an array of Matches (characters), 64 bytes**

```cs
s=>System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(s,"(?<![b-z]).")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fU9Nb8IwDL33V4SeEgnyB/qxQwWncYEJDhOHkLklLKQsdiDjz3e006SKSViy9fz8/KVxptF0AY1r2PobCU7yDSLJFTTBKj@PZw@IpnWYJYvgdI7k79rpUpE@VK21oOleLVnNig6L8vmMnoIoh2ZAjtOUv@ST9/3sthMyFV2WbL0heDUO@O8iWbVOK@I1Tw9NDR96r4ZgP4/mjxjj1p3GKbteAqH/Oj/wD@l/wRj3ngpZKaR8OL3kQq6hf51HVpQsyo2yAYQQWcJG1v0A)

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 20 + 1 bytes

```
gsub /(?<!a|\b)./,''
```

1 extra byte for the `p` command line option:

```ruby
$ ruby -p alphabet_cypher.rb <<< "hgfedcbaedcbalkjihgfedcbalkjihgfedcbaonmlkjihgfedcba wvutsrqponmlkjihgfedgfedcbarqponmlkjihgfedcbalkjihgfedcbadcba"
hello world
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P724NElBX8PeRjGxJiZJU09fR139//@M9LTUlOSkRDCRk52VCRNAZufn5SJzFcrLSkuKiwoL0MTRuJgKkNkg/C@/oCQzP6/4v24BAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), `-ir`, `-lp`, <s>9</s> 7 bytes

```
(⑩(a-|_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//9f49HElRqJujXx//9npKelpiQnJSYW5Ofl5mRnZcIE0PmVFeVlpSXFRYXoEgpQGk0YmQ0h4VxUhVDqv25m0X/dnAIA)

*2 bytes saved thanks to @A̲̲ suggesting to use a for loop over a while loop*

### Answer History

```
{!|⑩(a-|_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//@/WrHm0cSVGom6NfH//2ekp6WmJCclJhbk5@XmZGdlwgTQ@ZUV5WWlJcVFhegSClAaTRiZDSHhXFSFUOq/bmbRf92cAgA)

```
{!|⑩(a-|_
{!|             #While there are still items on the stack:
   ⑩            #Print t.o.s without popping
    (a-|            #Subtract the code point of a from tos and repeat that many times:
        _           #Pop items off the stack
```

Comment: [7 bytes](https://tio.run/##y05N//9f49HElRqJujXx//9npKelpiQnJSYW5Ofl5mRnZcIE0PmVFeVlpSXFRYXoEgpQGk0YmQ0h4VxUhVDqv25m0X/dnAIA). A simple optimization from while to for. (Your current program also generates an error in the end, so..)

Comment: @A  No, not at all. I... I wouldn't have thought of using a for loop... I was going to add a 'loop while there are still items on the stack' command to get this down to 6 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, 20 bytes

```
s:[^a]*a(.):a$_\1:g;
```

is **almost** there.  Unfortunately, it will lose the first letter, and I don’t know how to get around that.

Comment: Just *add* an a on the beginning! "a$_" =~ ....

Comment: Doesn’t $ match the end of the string?  And the underscore?

Comment: $_ is the string! "a$_" is equivalent to concatenating "a" and $_ ...

Comment: I edited according to how I interpret your comment, but either it's wrong or I misunderstood.  What I put in would make every output start with 'a'.  Can you edit it so that it is correct?  (Not that it competes with the length of a few others.)

Comment: Oh, no, I meant, apply the regex to "a$_" (I'm assuming you use "perl -ne" or "perl -pe", so each line will be available as $_).

Comment: OK, that adds seven more bytes if I stick to ASCII.

Answer (score 3):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 41 characters

```
\A\P?=?
 \P?=$0
?\P?=@cmps{?;?;$2;$2;}
?=
```

Unfortunately recognizers can not be combined. ☹

Sample run:

```
bash-5.0$ gema '\A\P?=$0; \P?=$0;?\P?=@cmps{$1;$2;$2;$2;};?=' <<< 'cbagfedcba cbacba'
cg cc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/NTfz/P8YxJsDe1p5LAUSpGHDZg2iH5NyC4mp7a3trFSMQquWyt/3/PzGxqLAgPy83JzsrMyM9LTUlOSkRjYvKUwBCUvUUk2oHjIFNpwKGg7A4B4TLSkuwaMeiGIkJAA)

Answer (score 3):

## C++,  464 bytes

I'm still a beginner so will be grateful for any advice.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  string input , output;
  getline(cin,input);
  output = input[0];

  for (int i = 0 ; i<input.size() ; i++) {
      if (input[i] == 'a')  {
          output += input[i+1];
      }  else if (input[i] == ' ') {
          output += input[i+1];
      }  else {
          continue;
      }

  }
  cout << output;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVBBboMwELz7FSP1AIi0Ss9APlJxcI2h28JCsN1KrXg7tSGhKDnVku3dmdkZ2WoYHhul5vmBWLWu0sipN3bUsjuJP8wjxM1JOOMvsOy0GaTSMLbKhCC26CRxnOBHAKsYxIOzOKB31heZJxptW2IdK@LDwiYBXXkU68DLsfSOQN2PiIMxeeaIDJQv/JOhb@2DPJCma15YVAd1mKcSRYFIRgk2NqxLTHrNofS5zC78BOjW6HsXRMm/TfZ61bMldnrThKdNIhDeJs@3z5nm@a2pdaVe5XK0H@90BfZ1z92@xdens2Y8Dzf4TXsv2Ndh/wI)

Comment: I don't know much about C++, but [212 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZYtBb4MwDIXv/RWWdmgiuqk7h/SPVByyYJgzsClJNmmI387opqmoPdh@73vPfhieW@@X5YnYd7lGKEliGtH1p92NrYS4Pe1yXA@w6zEOziPEVBviBL0jVnr6qwEdxLSYOmJUnvhA2ghYoPOxMo2M6voR7NGEkl4ifaPSJhSFnqhRdA6VtXu315MUdnXFa2Vm7CLCLYXHdPLCiTijmWcvOZWlmHlZ3tsGa//mflf3EegfbLVwv7Xw9ZlTHC/DHb@zj4Wtvs4P "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: Also, welcome to CGCC! I hope you enjoy golfing answers to challenges while you're here!

Comment: Get a warning for [159 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZYxBDoIwEADvvqKJB9oUDV4p5SOEA5aCW6FFKJoovr0iqCF42M3MZLOiaXalEM5tQYuqz2UEprOtzOp480tjAF3GmzoDjcmjs3kYzg2Bb1gpbQVa4qkL0D4QVpgWg7ZI8YCpCPYd3CUmTFFKoMCQqJRzL/OG4YPII4byUeghZfMj09sogiRIqWFP505lIXNxzKZVnRV8w5KNrpeKbtfedu2lWfWV/h8s@T0v)

Comment: As a first step, definitely remove all whitespace (including newline) and unneeded `{}`.  And always use single-letter variable names.  You can include an "ungolfed" version of your code in your answer (with newlines and comments) so people can read it.  See also [Tips for golfing in C++](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/132)

Comment: The `<string>` header is already included in `<iostream>`, the number of times you need `std::` is way less bytes than `using namespace std;`, `std::string::operator[](size_t pos)` will `return` `'\0'` for `pos == size()`. and your `if` statement can be collapsed to checking if the current character is less than 98(`'b'`). [122 bytes](https://tio.run/##lY7NDoIwEITvPkUTL23AhKPSwosQDrWUughdhOLF@OwVMSb@9EI2m8xM9suO6vudUcr7LVjVTpUWgKMbtOzyTSfBUnYbXZWmcwbWEIiRG@1asJouuQIbA@OYQZGUvMaBgnWkyRIORVNyBjWdRRSV4rBnGGVL@iJxckIgv3sv5XDp0XbtuYGTqXWljvLHfjsyz1pmXPvjLUIk@SsUqPPc6@QCeOD4Qz4A). :-)

Comment: And just found out about `#import` to save another byte [121 bytes](https://tio.run/##lY7NDoIwEITvPkUTLzRgwlFp8UUIh1pKXbRdLMWL8dkrYkz86YVsNpmZ7Jcd2fcbLWUIazA9Os8BB@@UMPuVEWATeht8UxRTBlYTyJBp5c9gVTLnEmwGlGEJVV6zFl0C1pOuzBlUXc0otMkk0rTmuy3FtJzTF4mj5xzZPQQh3KVHa86nDo66VY08iB/77cg0S5lh6Y@3iJHkr1CkznOvo4/gkeMP@QA).

Comment: Building on @Noodle9 [119 bytes](https://tio.run/##lU5ND4IwDL37K5Z4gYCJR2VDf4jhMMeYRbbOMbwYfzsOjYkfu5Cm7Xt9fWmFtSslxDguQVt0ngH23kmudwvNwSRgPGnTW@/roggCGEUgR6qk78DI5DkXYHJIaYMuwRIObbmuaGgVTUPNsoptN3vMJqUqkL4sOHjGkN7HkXN3sWh0d27hpBpZiyP/od@MhJjr6efeeIOYk/w9FHlnyuvgI/bI8gd8AA "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 50 bytes

```python
import re
f=lambda s:re.sub('([b-z]).*?a',r'\1',s)
```

Regex stolen from [Arnauld's JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/196467).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PzO3IL@oRKEolSvNNicxNyklUaHYqihVr7g0SUNdIzpJtypWU0/LPlFdp0g9xlBdp1jzf0FRZl6JRppGZl5BaYmGpqbm/4z0tNSU5KREMJGTnZUJE0Bm5@flInMVystKS4qLCgvQxNG4mAqQ2SAMAA)

Comment: You can save [2 more bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPqfZhvzPycxNyklUaHYqihVr7g0SUNdIzpJtypWU0/LPlFdp0g9xlBdp1iTKzO3IL@oRKEo9X9BUWZeiUaaRmZeQWmJhqam5v@M9LTUlOSkRDCRk52VCRNAZufn5SJzFcrLSkuKiwoL0MTRuJgKkNkgDAA) easily...

Comment: @game0ver I'm not familiar with the rules of the site, but does that count as a function?

Comment: Yes `lambda` is autonomous except for e.g. a recursive function where you need to refer to `f`...

Comment: @game0ver But you can't just do something like `print((lambda s:... import re)(input()))` right?

Comment: If you mean to place that all in the Footer then no. Your code must be an autonomous complete function/program. A `lambda` can be used standalone in a e.g. `map` etc...

Comment: works fine in earlier versions of python3 and even in python 2.7.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>87</s> <s>86</s> 84 bytes

```python
lambda i:"".join(x[:2]if'a'>x else x[0]for x in i.replace('a','a#').split('#')[:-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVLBjoIwEL37FRM8FJKVqEcS/RHkMGi71q2lC6h1f55FBBZKu8Y0bV5n3rRvXqvu5TGT64ptdpXAc3pA4JHnhaeMS1/H0TrhjCDZaqCioKDjZcKyHDRwCTzMqRK4p37N@CA4J0FYKMFLn9QwjharJKhUzmUJzPeOn4we9ik2i/g68S4wxJk8D7dwu17KIv9WRtzYTglD/JheMOuFYIpttEk/SS23q@mL/45xnD669l@VpsaJ6GkbltZtdlg9sjvnMFQ74ndX4seZGVmNL9/OePB6vFtTvHtHB2yVMBFkkeO210J2WNNXqBffxGk02JsdYuMzj4m9qOoX)

Non-regex effort. Replaces `a` with `a` plus a disposable character then splits on the disposable character and outputs either the first or first two letters of each list element depending on whether the first is a space or not.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 20 bytes

```
O0;ṡ2_/>0ƊÐḟṪ€Ọ
ḲÇ€K
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/fwPrhzoVG8fp2Bse6Dk94uGP@w52rHjWtebi7h@vhjk2H24Fs7////2ekp6WmJCclgomc7KxMmAAyOz8vF5mrUF5WWlJcVFiAJo7GxVSAzAZhAA)

probably too long lol

## Explanation

```
O0;ṡ2_/>0ƊÐḟṪ€Ọ  This challenge, for one word
O                turn all the chars to their ASCII forms
 0;              prepend 0
   ṡ2            split into (overlapping) slices of length 2 (pairs)
          Ðḟ     filter: remove elements where
     _/          reducing over subtraction (which is equivalent to the first minus the second, in each pair)
       >0        is greater than 0 (if it's strictly descending)
            Ṫ€   take the second element of each pair
              Ọ  convert back to chars
ḲÇ€K             Compiled Program
Ḳ                split on spaces
 Ç€              apply the helper to each word
   K             join on spaces
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 8 bytes

```
Φθ‹§θ⊖κb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMtM6cktUijUEfBJ7W4WMOxxDMvJbUCxHdJTS5KzU3NK0lN0cjW1NRRUEpS0tTUtP7/PyM9LTUlOSkxsSA/LzcnOysTJoDOr6woLystKS4qRJdQgNJowshsCAnnoiqEUlz/dctyAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
 θ          Input string
Φ           Filtered where
    θ       Input string
   §        Cyclically indexed by
      κ     Current index
     ⊖      Decremented
  ‹         Is less than
       b    Literal string `b`
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 67 bytes

Non-regex effort. I can't use regex because Wren doesn't support it..

```
Fn.new{|x|x.replace(" "," a").split("a")[0..-2].map{|i|(i+"a")[0]}}
```

### Explanation

```
Fn.new{|x|                                                        } // New anonymous function with parameter x.
          x.replace(" "," a")                                       // Append spaces with the a character in order to make them individual.
                             .split("a")                            // Split into a list with the character a.
                                        [0..-2]                     // We have a trailing unused a, so we need to remove it.
                                               .map{|i|          }  // Foreach this list:
                                                       (i+"a")      // Append this item with an a character(since we have used it for the splitting function)
                                                              [0]   // Return the first item in this list
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYy7EsIgEEV/haFKRmUcewsbf8DSSUGQKEoQCXkZ8u2YGB95kGLvnnt2ZnNFhc2wAlEqCNgCuxdI0LwyhSmQopJjQj0I4BICDH2USM60Bxs8rhFabQIUY1kZZjy26GxQ1/ZQJprGSCom9I5zr/2NCG4I4hCTEJ@aoW1E7zx36/LZ7AvXH93@yHsc94sYtPuwylF/jIWamGSqtMOlLpk5be7WxYwv5w7P2Qv0ffsC)

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 35 bytes

```java
s->s.replaceAll("([b-z]).*?a","$1")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVJNc4IwEL37K3aYHsDRzPRaWzu99NaTR8fDgmCDAdIk0GLH357ypUVIdBwm7Nfbl81LYixwHm/3miY8EwriKia5ooxEeRoomqVkupgEDKWED6Qp/E4AeO4zGoBUqCpTZHQLSVVzV0rQdLfeAIqd9BoowHvH89xWZ61ZQgQvWs6XkoiQMwzCN8Zcx13788PGI9NXdGbOw6Pj6UXDEmXCLVDUzE8X9ACrUqowIVmuCK@oFUvdiCDnrHQroOe1BMdJvY5af@6icBv42PzYPqanRN/P0qQfwneRKym@@CA/CMeAvl8vjT52bpNrKx3gBDx3/PdaKC/2ujracLDRpOPZDec1aWAUxiyXRcUfS760FQ7Wika8eUuDq62@e3vkvXucHFMnjAYyjGPX1ADu63GG8RsPwiopmE/Y9wfP9hLYmT8)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 18 bytes

```
({.;.2~'a'=])&>@;:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/Nar1rPWM6tQT1W1jNdXsHKyt/mtypSZn5CukKahnpKelpiQnJSYW5Ofl5mRnZcIE0PmVFeVlpSXFRYXoEgpQGk0YmQ0h4VxUhVBKHe6kxERMS9C4aC4AQlL1FJNqBzygsAUBhoOwOAeEsYcgFsVITPX/AA)

Comment: [You don't need the outer parenthesis.](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/Nar1rPWM6tQT1W1jNdXsHKyt/mtypSZn5CukKahnpKelpiQnJSYW5Ofl5mRnZcIE0PmVFeVlpSXFRYXoEgpQGk0YmQ0h4VxUhVBKHe6kxERMS9C4aC4AQlL1FJNqBzygsAUBhoOwOAeEsYcgFsVITPX/AA "J – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```
{'`+]2CO:so)[-}ww\[
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f@/Wj1BO9bI2d@qOF8zWre2vDwm@v//jPS01JTkpMTEgvy83JzsrEyYADq/sqK8rLSkuKgQXUIBSqMJI7MhJJyLqhBKAQA)

Non-regex solution, can save 2 bytes if permitted to return list of chars

```
{
 `'+] # Prefix each word with a backtick
 2CO  # Create n-grams of length 2 (abc => {ab bc})
 :so  # Filter for those which are in alphabetical order
 )[-  # Take the last letter of each n-gram
}ww   # For each word
\[    # Concatenate to string
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
wmom←ġ<w
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8dC2/@W5@bmP2iYcWWhT/v///4z0tNSU5KREMJGTnZUJE0Bm5@flInMVystKS4qLCgvQxNG4mAqQ2SDMlZiUCGWCxSAyUAUwhXAdCL04jESxC6/T0B2G4VJMt2PxL7YwwBow2IMLRyhW4BCvxCVRhVOGKzGRYCyhRS0QkqqnmFQ7YAxsOhUwHITFObjDFIti5PCAKysgkCBwBqkCdh8is9GSLapCKAUA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 67 bytes

According to the definition, we don't have to worry about invalid input. So I'm not actually checking if all the letters between the intended letter and "a" are properly following the reverse alphabet order, or even if there's the right number of letters. Feels a bit dirty, but it works for all valid input :)

```php
for($x=0;$c=$argn[$x++];){$l=$l?$l:$c;if(ord($c)<98){echo$l;$l=0;}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNFQqbA2sVZJtVRKL0vOiVSq0tWOtNatVcmxVcuxVcqxUkq0z0zTyi1I0VJI1bSwtNKtTkzPyVXKsgSoMrGtr///PSE9LTUlOSkwsyM/LzcnOyoQJoPMrK8rLSkuKiwrRJRSgNJowMhtCwrmoCqHUv/yCksz8vOL/um4A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `B`, 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
0ƤṢ⁺Vi
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPTAlQzYlQTQlRTElQjklQTIlRTIlODElQkFWaSZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PWhnZmVkY2JhZWRjYmFsa2ppaGdmZWRjYmFsa2ppaGdmZWRjYmFvbm1sa2ppaGdmZWRjYmElMjB3dnV0c3JxcG9ubWxramloZ2ZlZGNiYW9ubWxramloZ2ZlZGNiYXJxcG9ubWxramloZ2ZlZGNiYWxramloZ2ZlZGNiYWRjYmEmZmxhZ3M9Qg==)

Port of Jonathan Allan's Jelly answer.

##### Explanation

```python
0ƤṢ⁺Vi  # Implicit input
0Ƥ      # Prepend a 0
  Ṣ     # Deltas
   ⁺    # Incremented
    V   # Truthy indices
     i  # Index in
        # Implicit output
```